# UIViewController -viewDidLoad not being called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Being new to Cocoa, I'm having a few issues with `Interface Builder`, `UIViewController` and friends.

I have a `UIViewController` subclass with a `UIView` defined in a xib, and with the controller's view outlet connected to the view. The xib's "file's owner" is set as *myViewcontroller* subclass.

In this one instance, the following code to load the controller/view (from the main view controller) doesn't work as expected:

```
if ( self.myViewController == nil )
{
    self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
}

[self.navigationController 
    pushViewController:self.myViewController animated:YES];
```

In MyViewController's methods, I have placed breakpoints and log messages to see what is going on:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        NSLog(@"initWithNibName\n");
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad\n");
}
```

**Expected result**

Both `-initWithNibName` and `-viewDidLoad` methods are called, and myViewController's view is displayed.

**Observed result**

Only `-initWithNibName` is called, the view is not displayed.

Have I missed something? Can anyone recommend anything to check? (Particularly in the wondrously opaque Interface Builder tool).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479576/viewdidload-not-called-in-subclassed-uiviewcontroller

Comment: you're having problems with friends?

Comment: I had "Inherit Module from Target" unchecked, checking it solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I have a partial answer - maybe the gurus can explain some more. The problem is:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Looking more closely, in this case `self.navigationController` is nil - so the push message is going no-where.

Instead, if I send:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.myViewController.view];
```

Then the view appears and `-viewDidLoad` is called.

I'm not entirely sure why `self.navigationController` is not set in this instance - the only thing I can think of is that `self` is a subclass of `UIViewController` rather than `UITableViewController` (where the `pushViewController` code came from).

Also, silently allowing messages to go to nil seems like a bad idea, although [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil)  say otherwise. See also my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914166/is-there-a-way-to-trap-messages-sent-to-nil-in-objective-c).

Final edit:

Answers in comments below, I've realised the display function that I was actually after (given myViewController is modal) is:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Thanks everyone for their helpful responses.

Comment: Don't badmouth silent-message-to-nil, you'll use it all the time when you get used to it :-)

It can certainly be mysterious when you first start out.

As for why navigationController is nil: is it being initialized as the root view controller of a UINavigationController? If not, you can't use pushViewController until you do that!

Comment: I think Adam has it exactly here, make sure your view is properly placed into a navigation stack before trying to get its navigationController.

Answer (score 36):

RE: SOLUTION FOUND!!!!!

Indeed that seems to be a working solution, however the real trick is not in setting the `view.hidden` property to NO, what makes the view load from the nib file is the calling of the `UIViewController's` view method, the view only actually gets loaded from the nib when the view method is called for the first time.

In that sense, a simple `[viewController view]` message would force the view to load from the nib file.

Comment: Best answer. [viewController view] <- This is what helps answer the op's question. That's how -viewDidLoad is called on demand.

Comment: You saved my day.  
Thanks a lot.

Comment: (swift) using `let _ = controller.view` did trigger viewDidLoad for me. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

SOLUTION FOUND!!!!!

Even something as innocuous as this makes the `viewDidLoad` method call happen.

Insert this right after alloc `initWithNibName`

```
viewController.view.hidden = NO; //calls viewDidLoad
```

Comment: that's because every time you use the view-property the getter and/or setter will trigger loading of the view. even just typing 'self.view;' would be sufficient enoguh

Comment: But doing that is probably not recommended, since it short circuits the whole lazy loading scheme.

Answer (score 5):

make sure that the view outlet in File's Owner (your viewController subclass) is connected to the actual view (i.e. the 480X320 canvas you see on your screen that you use to build your UI)

Comment: Yeah thanks, that is certainly the case - I mentioned that above, but just double-checked.

Answer (score 5):

Chances are that you might not have linked the supposed `ViewController` in `main.storyboard` from the `Identity Inspector` to the custom `class` you created. You might be able to navigate to that controller from other view controllers via segues but any of `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear()` etc. won't be executed.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        //Your Code here
  }
```

instead of the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason, somewhat obvious in retrospect: if `viewController.view` is set in code, then the viewDidLoad event will not trigger.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a capitalization problem to me.  You're referencing the class `MyViewController` instead of the property `myViewController` in the call to pushViewController.

Comment: My bad that was just a typo while moving code to stackoverflow - I'm fixing the question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check your run log for errors. Almost certainly, the NIB is not loading, and there should be an error to that effect. The most likely cause for that is failure to put it in the bundle. Look in your "Copy Resources" build phase and make sure that the XIB is actually being copied. Build for the simulator, and go down into the build directory and make sure that the NIB is in the .app bundle.

Comment: All good points, CompileXIB is being called, and MyViewController is both in the Copy Resources phase and appearing in the app package. Checked this a few times with a clean build.
Also I modified the -initWithNibName NSLog to write 'self', with the result: "initWithNibName self=<MyViewController: 0x56c180>", so it looks like its being loaded.

Comment: initWithNibName:bundle: doesn't load the NIB. The first call to -view loads the NIB (so checking self doesn't prove anything). Check that self.naviagationController isn't nil. If it were, then you'd never actually load the NIB. Also, you're likely leaking in your assignment to self.myViewController (assuming it's a "retain" property, which it should be). You need to autorelease it. Kudos for using accessors there, though. In Cocoa, when "nothing happens" something is nil. The most common case is you didn't wire it in IB.

Comment: Ah thanks Rob, didn't see your comment there - the problem was in fact that self.navigationController was nil. Not sure why (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers here,

It often happens when the identifier with which you instantiate your ViewController from the storyboard is incorrect. For e.g.

`[[self getStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:MyVC];`

If `MyVC` is the identifier of some other ViewController, this might happen.

OP is using `nib` instead of storyboard here. But the answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

**The page has been presented but not visible in Debug view hierarchy & in device(simulator also), issue happens based on and
i found the fix:**

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews{
     if day == true{
            self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
     }else{
            self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
     }
}
```

**Don't try to implement the self.view (viewcontrollers view) in function of layoutsubviews.** So better use self.view in viewwillappear or viewdidload. This issue happens starts from v-14 devices.

Hope it works for you too.