# -viewDidLoad not called in subclassed UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Have patience with me, I'm still learning Cocoa Touch.  Other -viewDidLoad not being called question was unrelated to my issue, I did search.

I have `FooViewController`, a `UIViewController` subclass. FooViewController.xib has its File's Owner set to FooViewController. Additionally, I have `Main`, whose App Delegate is `MyApplication` and whose File's Owner is `UIApplication`. My primary nib is set to Main.

I am able to make the view appear on the screen, using this flow (code snipped for brevity):

```
UIWindow *main;

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application {
    [self showFooViewController];
    [main makeKeyAndVisible];
}

-(void)showFooViewController {
    fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
    if(![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooViewController" owner:fooViewController options:nil]) {
        DebugF(@"Failed to load FooViewController");
        return;
    }

    // Add the view and put it in place
    UIView *view = [fooViewController view];
    CGRect cur = [view frame];
    cur.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 20.0f);
    [view setFrame:cur];

    [main addSubview:[fooViewController view]];
}
```

However, this message is not being sent to `FooViewController`:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    DebugF(@"Hello!");
}
```

Total silence in gdb's output.

I've seen other Cocoa tutorials that show Instances and such in IB's document view, but I do not see these options in mine.  Am I supposed to be instantiating fooViewController in the Nib?  Did I miss a connection?  In FooViewController.xib, File's Owner view is connected to the view in the Nib.

I'm sure this is a simple solution, and I have wandered down the wrong path.  Halp!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have not found documentation to back up the following, but this is what I've deduced by experiment / experience:

The `viewDidLoad` method is expected be called immediately after `loadView` is called, and it's up to whomever calls `loadView` to supply the extra call to `viewDidLoad`.

In some cases, the SDK will handle this behavior for you.  Suppose you have a subclass of `UIViewController` called `MyViewController`; then:

- If you access `myViewController.view` before you call `loadView`, then the superclass accessor is smart enough to call `loadView` for you, and `viewDidLoad` immediately thereafter.

As a result, if your code looks like this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[superView addSubview:myViewController.view];  // Calls viewDidLoad.
```

then both `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` will be called on your behalf.

However, if your code looks like this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[myViewController loadView];
[superView addSubview:myViewController.view];  // Doesn't call viewDidLoad.
```

then the `view` getter can see you've already loaded the view, and it assumes you also called `viewDidLoad` as well - so it doesn't call either.  Ironically, the extra function call here prevents `viewDidLoad` from getting called.

Comment: According to the documentation "You should never call this method [loadView] directly".

Comment: Thanks, Peter - I see what you're referring to.  Here's the link, in case anyone wants to read the original source (from Apple):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView

Comment: I had exactly the same problem (calling `loadView` directly), thanks for the info.

Comment: I use this format: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooViewController" owner:fooViewController options:nil]; [self viewDidLoad];`  which calls for `[super viewDidLoad];` and everyone's happy :)

Comment: AWESOME REASEARCH!!!!  I wish I could up vote more than one point.  Thank you for this.

Comment: @Tyler hi but when i want to presentViewController at that time it does not call the viewdidLoad method. What should i do for this please help me ?

Answer (score 4):

And I've answered my own question, so this may help future folks. Since I see viewDidLoad has, as its three top Googles in my suggest, "viewDidLoad not called", "viewDidLoad not getting called", and "viewDidLoad not firing", I imagine this is a usual mistake...

Changing:

```
fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
if(![[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooViewController" owner:fooViewController options:nil]) {
    DebugF(@"Failed to load FooViewController");
    return;
}
```

To:

```
fooViewController = [[FooViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Fixed the problem.  Obviously a mistake in how I'm using Cocoa.

Comment: It's a small thing, but if you pass nil for the bundle, it'll look in the main bundle.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latter call makes it impossible to specify options, which means you can't use proxy objects.  But it sounds like I'll just have to ignore viewDidLoad and call my own method manually.

Answer (score 4):

I have had this same problem twice. The first time, I forgot to connect the view of UITableViewController to the actual UITableView in interface builder. The second time, I forgot to make `awakeFromNib` call itself in the superclass.