# iPhone Cocos2D - where to load the code?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am starting to learning Cocos2D for iPhone. I see the basic template has a viewController but when it runs it loads HelloWorldLayer, instead of the viewController view.

When you work with a viewController, you used to have the main logic for that controller on the .m, but as Cocos2D works in another way I wonder where should I put the main logic code.

What I mean is this. Developing with Cocos2D I will have a bunch of these "layer" files and as I pass the scenes, one of these files will be active at one time but now imagine that I am building an app that has in-app purchases or coredata. I have to have one central place where this common logic to handle sales and the database should reside. Where is the best practice? To put it on the viewController Cocos2D creates or what? How do you do that?

Where do I put the code so it will initialize when the app runs and before showing the first scene?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The startup code in Cocos2D is in the app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching method. So you may want to initialize your loading code there.

The issue you're experiencing may be due to the incorrect setup of the view controller by Cocos2D, which leads to the view controller's viewDidLoad method not to be called. You can call that manually from applicationDidFinishLaunching however, after the line: `rootViewController.view = glView`

You'll find plenty of Tutorials that shed more light on this here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Comment: thanks. What do you mean by call manually? At the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching I see [viewController setView:glView] and then [window addSubview:viewController.view] and even so, viewController's viewDidLoad is not called... any thoughts? thanks.

Comment: That's because Cocos2D doesn't follow this guideline: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479576/viewdidload-not-called-in-subclassed-uiviewcontroller
To fix this, simply call viewDidLoad yourself after this line:  rootViewController.view = glView;
[rootViewController viewDidLoad];