# viewDidLoad method not being called using presentModalDialog method

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am using presentModalDialog to show a viewcontroller's view however the viewDidLoad never gets called?!

Is there any method that is called where I can place my logic that fills and configures the view?

EDIT:

It's a bit difficult to put a small amount of code, you kind of need to see it all, but here goes:

I have 2 nibs and 2 view controllers (portrait-mainvc/landscape) which both inherit from 1 baseclass which has the logic and the iboutlets.  This is to allow me to re-use code.  When the orientation changes in the main controller, it switches between the 2 controllers (modal dialog) which in turn use their respective nib's however they all use the same base code to configure the UI items.

```
@implementation HomeViewControllerBase

- (void)configureBestSellItems
{
    [self startRetrievingRegions];

    // load all the images from our bundle and add them to the scroll view
    //  NSUInteger i;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 150; i++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = @"tempImage.jpg";
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
        [self.bestSellScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }

    [self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureBestSellItems];
}

@end

@interface HomeViewController : HomeViewControllerBase
{

}

@interface HomeViewController_Landscape : HomeViewControllerBase
{

}

@implementation HomeViewController

//This works for portrait
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end

@implementation HomeViewController_Landscape

//This does not work
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

//This works as suggested
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super configureBestSellItems];
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you provide some code? Sounds strange, have you remembered to call the super class implementation of viewDidLoad?

Comment: +1 for posting some code. `viewDidLoad` will always be called so something's up in your implementation.

Comment: @Andreas - I have added some code, am keen to hear your opinion

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong at the code you provided... And your app launches correctly? And you probably have tested with a NSLog in both the base controller and the derived one straitght after the super invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these in your viewcontroller:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   [super awakeFromNib];
   // your code here
}
```

or

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // your code here
}
```

However, you should try to find why viewDidLoad is never called. You can also check this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913627/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-not-being-called).

Comment: Don't really like this answer. `awakeFromNib` may work but `viewWillAppear` will have undesirable side effects as the view can appear/disappear w/o needing to be reloaded. It would be far better to figure out why `viewDidLoad` "isn't being called." Hard to say w/o seeing some code. That's the proper place to modify the view whenever it is loaded.

Comment: Another reason I don't like `awakeFromNib` is it's specific to using IB. If you're like me and you eventually decide to create all of your views programmatically, `awakeFromNib` will no longer be called. If you fix and use `viewDidLoad` you won't have to change code after replacing what IB creates with `loadView`. If you do try use `awakeFromNib`, make sure to call `[super awakeFromNib]` as the first line.

Comment: this works but am keen to hear what @XJones thinks of my edited post

Answer (score 0):

You may have a custom function in there named presentModalDialog:, as searching apple's docs doesn't have that function. You're calling a custom function that loads a Xib.

I'm doing the same thing.

You want this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller...
```

ViewDidLoad is called by Controllers, if the awakeFromNib is being called, you're probably getting, by itself, the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem in objective c:
you should review the flowing:

1-initiation of the view controller you should initialize it in the right way in  app delegate.
2-review the file owner of the view it must be the right class which usually the same name of uiview.