# presentViewController not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, presentviewcontroller

Thank you for reading this. I would like to have a functions Swift file where I put all of the functions for my project into, that the other Swift files could call. I am trying to create an alert function in the functions file that, when I pass in a specific string, it shows a specific alert. It was working when it was in the main file, but when I moved it to the functions file, presentViewController is giving me an error, saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'presentViewController'." Please help! Here is my code:
in the functions file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

/**********************************************
Variables
***********************************************/
var canTapButton: Bool = false
var tappedAmount = 0

/**********************************************
Functions
***********************************************/

//the alert to ask the user to assess their speed
func showAlert(alert: String) -> Void
{
if(alert == "pleaseAssessAlert")
{
    let pleaseAssessAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "If this is your firs time, I encourage you to use the Speed Assessment Tool (located in the menu) to figure which of you fingers is fastest!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    //ok button
    let okButtonOnAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default)
        { (action) -> Void in
            //what happens when "ok" is pressed
    }
    pleaseAssessAlert.addAction(okButtonOnAlertAction)

    presentViewController(pleaseAssessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    println("Error calling the alert function.")
}    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `presentViewController` is the instance method of [**UIViewController**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) class. So you can't access it on your function file like this.

You should change the function like:

```
func showAlert(alert : String, viewController : UIViewController) -> Void
{
   if(alert == "pleaseAssessAlert")
   {
       let pleaseAssessAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "If this is your firs time, I encourage you to use the Speed Assessment Tool (located in the menu) to figure which of you fingers is fastest!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
       //ok button
       let okButtonOnAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default)
       { (action) -> Void in
            //what happens when "ok" is pressed
       }
       pleaseAssessAlert.addAction(okButtonOnAlertAction)
       viewController.presentViewController(pleaseAssessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   else
   {
       println("Error calling the alert function.")
   }    
}
```

Here, you are passing a `UIViewController` instance to this function and calling the `presentViewController` of that View Controller class.

Comment: I switched it to 'ViewController.presentViewController(pleaseAssessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)' and now it is returning the following error: "Extra argument 'animated' in call."

Comment: @user3338042: The same code works for me without any error. Also check the code. I used `viewController` as parameter. In your code it's `ViewController`. So check whether it is correctly typed or not (If not then you are using the Class name, that causes the issue. Change that and it'll work)

Comment: VeiwController is a class of UIViewController. What should I pass in the place of viewController?

Comment: You need to pass the `ViewController` class instance. call like : `showAlert("pleaseAssessAlert", self);` if you are calling from a ViewController class. You need to copy above mentioned method, don't change the `viewController` to `ViewController`

Answer (score 5):

### In Swift 3:

The method `presentViewController` is replaced by `present`.

You can use it like the old one:

```
self.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check your NavigationController is appropriate or not?
If Yes, then Here is code for present and dismiss presentviewcontroller

**For presenting PresentViewController :**

`let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Your view controller identifier") as! Yourviewcontroller
        self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)`

**Dismiss Presentviewcontroller**

`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Answer (score 0):

I would say go with MidHun MP method above but, if you are looking for another way to do this without bringing in the UIViewController then:

```
func showAlert(alert : String) {
   var window: UIWindow?

   if(alert == "pleaseAssessAlert")
   {
       let pleaseAssessAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: "If this is your firs time, I encourage you to use the Speed Assessment Tool (located in the menu) to figure which of you fingers is fastest!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
       //ok button
       let okButtonOnAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default)
       { (action) -> Void in
            //what happens when "ok" is pressed
       }
       pleaseAssessAlert.addAction(okButtonOnAlertAction)
       self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(pleaseAssessAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   else
   {
       println("Error calling the alert function.")
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presenting & navigation view controller has a problem with `layoutsubviews` function while using `self.view` or `viewcontroller.view`, so one must avoid those function.

Check:
[func layoutsubviews not allows to provide the viewcontroller.view to work on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65965184/15074740)