# What would be a do nothing operator for a function returning void?

Tags: objective-c

I want to return nothing inside a function returning void. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Structure the flow of the code so that there is no need for a return statement.
2. Place `return;` statements where you want the function to return control to the caller.

EDIT: *To clarify, `return;` is a statement that returns control to the caller without yielding a value.*

That's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

i think sending a message to nil is a no-op

```
[nil message]
```

[Sending a message to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil/160432#160432)