# Objective-C why doesn't my array of array works?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multidimensional-array

This is probably a completely stupid question, but i'm pretty new at objective-C and programing in general.
i'm trying to make an array of arrays but can't manage to make it work :

```
@interface ArraysAndDicts : NSObject {
 NSMutableArray * mySimpleArray;
 NSMutableArray * myComplicatedArray;
}
```

the implementation :

```
-(void)generateValueForArrayOfArrays {

    [self generateValueForArray]; 
    //this generates an array with 5 elements 'mySimpleArray'

    [myComplicatedArray addObject:mySimpleArray];

    NSMutableArray * mySecondaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [mySecondaryArray addObject:@"twoone"];
    [mySecondaryArray addObject:@"twotwo"];

    [myComplicatedArray addObject:mySecondaryArray];
```

(i edited out all the NSLogs for clarity)

When running my app, the console tells me :

> mySecondaryArray count =  2
>
> mySimpleArray count = 5
>
> myComplicatedArraycount = 0

So, i know there are other ways to make multidimensional arrays,
but i'd really like to know why this doesn't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're never creating `myComplicatedArray`. This means that

```
[myComplicatedArray addObject:mySimpleArray];
```

is actually

```
[nil addObject:mySimpleArray];
```

Sending messages to nil simply has no effect in Objective-C, so nothing happens. When you ask for the count of the array, you're effectively sending `[nil count]`, which will return 0 in your case. You can find [more information about sending messages to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil) here.

---

Also, when you're doing

```
NSMutableArray * mySecondaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[mySecondaryArray addObject:@"twoone"]; 
[mySecondaryArray addObject:@"twotwo"];
```

`mySecondaryArray` will leak. You should release it, either with `autorelease`

```
NSMutableArray * mySecondaryArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
...
```

or `release`, whichever is appropriate.

```
NSMutableArray * mySecondaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...
[mySecondaryArray release];
```

Comment: oooh indeed. I forgot to initialize it >.< in knew that was a stupid question ;)

Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can't see how `myComplicatedArray` is initialised. Perhaps it's `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize `myComplicatedArray` somewhere?

```
myComplicatedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self generateValueForArray];
// etc...
```