# set array empty

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a clear history button which clears the data in plist. Now, loading is fine; I load it to an array.

Can I just use:

```
self.dataClear = NULL;
```

and save back the array to plist to clear it?
So that I can use

```
if([self.dataClear count] == 0)//if plist is empty
```

to check?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd probably be better off using a `NSMutableArray` and calling `removeAllObjects` on that instead of NULLing it out; otherwise, there won't be any object there to respond to your `count` message, since there's a conceptual difference between "empty array" and "no array at all".

Comment: Although a mutable array most likely fits better, sending messages to `nil` is fine in this case - see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil).

Comment: Indeed, though I wanted to stress that distinction between `nil` and empty, since I consider `count` working as expected here somewhat of a fringe case. Nevertheless, your point is correct.

Comment: i set to nil, it doesn't work, use removeALlobjects and it works.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed to do a table refresh.