# Is asserting that every object creation succeeded necessary in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

I have recently read Apple's sample code for [MVCNetworking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MVCNetworking/) written by Apple's Developer Technical Support guru Quinn "The Eskimo!". The sample is really nice learning experience with what I guess are best development practices for iOS development.
What surprised me, coming from JVM languages, are extremely frequent assertions like this:

```
syncDate = [NSDate date];
assert(syncDate != nil);
```

and this:

```
photosToRemove = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:knownPhotos];
assert(photosToRemove != nil);
```

and this:

```
photoIDToKnownPhotos = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
assert(photoIDToKnownPhotos != nil);
```

Is that really necessary? Is that coding style worth emulating?

Comment: No wonder I see so many dynamic web pages with Null pointer exceptions....

Comment: Suggest you read this article on [Defensive Programming](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-09-defensive-programming.html)

Comment: From the article: "An assert should only be for constraint which, if broken, will lead to a crash or data corruption. Asserting early and causing a deliberate crash with concrete information about the reason is better than crashing later."

Though it seems to me like a downward spiral to start questioning every object creation, especially small objects, and guarding it with assert. There does not seem to be end to this paranoia, once you go that way, does it?

Comment: Everything in moderation. The key is to recognize the peril of any operation on your 'data' and handle using the appropriate tool/method available. Assertions are one of many 'guards' available to you. At higher levels of abstraction, you may choose to bundle your data operations into atomic units of work. An important technique when concurrency is considered. Your level of paranoia increases with the level of 'importance' of your data and the level of difficulty required to 'undo' changes *WHEN* something goes wrong, not *IF* something goes wrong

Comment: @Palimondo: preventing you from having to be paranoid about every object creation is (I guess) why Objective-C is designed so that you can safely send messages to `nil` in most cases. I've edited my answer to explain this further. I'm assuming that this design predates the inclusion of optional exception handling support in the language. In C on the other hand, you'd have to be paranoid about `malloc` returning `NULL`, at least if you want your application to end gracefully rather than crash, since C doesn't have a similar design where doing something with `NULL` is usually safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're used to Java, this may seem strange. You'd expect an object creation message to throw an exception when it fails, rather than return `nil`. However, while [Objective-C on Mac OS X has support for exception handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH13-SW1); it's an optional feature that can be turned on/off with a compiler flag. The standard libraries are written so they can be used without exception handling turned on: hence messages often return `nil` to indicate errors, and sometimes require you to also pass a pointer to an `NSError*` variable. (This is for Mac development, I'm not sure whether you can even turn exception handling support on for iOS, considering you also can't turn on garbage collection for iOS.)

The [section "Handling Initialization Failure"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13) in the document "The Objective-C Programming Language" explains how Objective-C programmers are expected to deal with errors in object initialization/creation: that is, return `nil`.

Something like `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path]` may definitely return `nil`: the documentation for the method explicitly says so. But I'm honestly not sure whether something like `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: n]` ever returns `nil`. The only situation I can think of when it *might* is when the application is out of memory. But in that case I'd expect the application to be aborted by the attempt to allocate more memory. I have not checked this though, and it may very well be that it returns `nil` in this case. While in Objective-C you can often [safely send messages to `nil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7), this could then still lead to undesirable results. For example, your application may try to make an `NSMutableArray`, get `nil` instead, and then happily continue sending `addObject:` to `nil` and write out an empty file to disk rather than one with elements of the array as intended. So in some cases it's better to check explicitly whether the result of a message was `nil`. Whether doing it at *every* object creation is necessary, like the programmer you're quoting is doing, I'm not sure. Better safe than sorry perhaps?

**Edit:** I'd like to add that while *checking* that object creation succeeded can sometimes be a good idea, *asserting* it may not be the best idea. You'd want this to be also checked in the release version of your application, not just in the debug version. Otherwise it kind of defeats the point of checking it, since you don't want the application end user to, for example, wind up with empty files because `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: n]` returned `nil` and the application continued sending messages to the `nil` return value. Assertions (with [`assert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/assert.3.html) or [`NSAssert`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/Tasks/AssertMacros.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000063-BCIFBACA)) can be removed from the release version with compiler flags;  Xcode doesn't seem to include these flags by default in the "Release" configuration though. But if you'd want to use these flags to remove some other assertions, you'd also be removing all your "object creation succeeded" checks.

**Edit:** Upon further reflection, it seems more plausible than I first thought that `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: n]` would return `nil` rather than abort the application when not enough memory is available. Basic C `malloc` also doesn't abort but returns a `NULL` pointer when not enough memory is available. But I haven't yet found any clear mention of this in the Objective-C documentation on [`alloc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-alloc) and similar methods.

**Edit:** Above I said I wasn't sure checking for `nil` is necessary at every object creation. But it shouldn't be. This is exactly why Objective-C allows sending messages to `nil`, which then return `nil` (or `0` or something similar, depending on the message definition): this way, `nil` can propagate through your code somewhat similar to an exception so that you *don't* have to explicitly check for `nil` at every single message that might return it. But it's a good idea to check for it at points where you don't want it to propagate, like when writing files, interacting with the user and so on, or in cases where the result of sending a message to `nil` is undefined (as explained in the [documentation on sending messages to `nil`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)). I'd be inclined to say this is like the "poor man's" version of exception propagation&handling, though not everyone may agree that the latter is better; but `nil` doesn't tell you anything about why an error occurred and you can easily forget to check for it where such checks are necessary.

Comment: Thank you for thorough explanation, especially for the clarification of what happens to assertions in Release builds. This seems to little bit contradict Sherm Pendley's comments in nearby answers, doesn't it?

Comment: BTW do you happen to be [this person](https://devforums.apple.com/people/Rincewind)?

Comment: You're welcome. I can't seem to log in at the Developer Forums at all for the moment, but I always use the Dutch spelling of the wizard's name so it's not me ;) (http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rinzwind)

Answer (score 2):

Yup. I think it's a good idea.. It helps to filter out the edge cases (out of memory, input variables empty/nil) as soon as the variables are introduced. Although I am not sure the impact on speed because of the overhead!

Comment: Yep, definitely a good idea! Assert() is a macro that expands to an empty string for release builds, so the only speed impact is for development builds.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's a matter of personal choice. Usually asserts are used for debugging purpose so that the app crashes at the assert points if the conditions are not met. You'd normally like to strip them out on your app releases though.

I personally am too lazy to place asserts around every block of code as you have shown. I think it's close to being a bit too paranoid. Asserts might be pretty handy in case of conditions where some uncertainity is involved.

Comment: No need to strip them out - assert() is a macro that expands to an empty string for release builds anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have [also asked this on Apple DevForums](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/93893?tstart=0). According to Quinn "The Eskimo!" (author of the MVCNetworking sample in question) it is a [matter of coding style and his personal preference](https://devforums.apple.com/message/408698#408698):

> I use lots of asserts because I hate debugging. (...)
>
> Keep in mind that I grew up with traditional Mac OS, where a single rogue pointer could bring down your entire machine (similarly to kernel programming on current systems).  In that world it was important to **find your bugs sooner rather than later**.  And lots of **asserts help** you do that.
>
> Also, even today I spend much of my life dealing with network programs.  Debugging network programs is hard because of the asynchrony involved.  Asserts help to with this, because they are continually checking the state of your program as it runs.
>
> However, I think you have a valid point with stuff like `+[NSDate date]`.  The chances of that returning nil are low.  The **assert is there purely from habit**.  But I think the **costs of this habit** (some extra typing, learning to ignore the asserts) **are small** compared to the benefits.

From this I gather that asserting that every object creation succeeded is not strictly necessary.

- Asserts can be valuable to **document the pre-conditions** in methods, during development, as design aid for other maintainers (including the future self). *I personally prefer the alternative style - to separate the specification and implementation using TDD/BDD practices.*
- Asserts can be used to **double-check runtime types** of method arguments due to the dynamic nature of Objective C:

  ```
  assert([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]);
  ```

I'm sure there are more good uses of assertions. All Things In Moderation...