# what happens when we invoke a method on a nil pointer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending a message to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil)

what happens when we invoke a method on a nil pointer

Answer (score 2):

It returns 0, nil, a structure filled with 0s, etc.

[Sending Messages to nil](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)