# Setting object to nil after release -- TT_RELEASE_SAFELY

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, three20

I have started to study Three20 and I have a simple question about `TT_RELEASE_SAFELY`
Up till now I like to write code in this way:

```
UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[self.view addSubview:lab];
[lab release];
```

Here I think the main pool is responsible to free the memory of `lab`.

Now I have found `TT_RELEASE_SAFELY` which is defined like so:

```
#define TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }
```

As you can see, after release, it sets the object to `nil`.

I'd like to know the difference between the two ways and which way is better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sending a message to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil) is valid in Objective-C.  Sending a message to a deallocated object is not.

Sending a message to a deallocated object:

```
id obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[obj release];
[obj doSomething]; // Crash!
```

Sending a message to nil:

```
id obj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[obj release], obj = nil;
[obj doSomething]; // Valid
```

---

Assigning nil to a variable after an object has been deallocated is controversial because it can prevent you from realizing that something is wrong.  Sedate Alien's example:

```
[controlCenter dealloc];
...
float timeLeft = [controlCenter timeToWaitBeforeBombDetonation];
```

This code will crash since controlCenter has been deallocated.  As a result this defect will be detected and fixed early.

```
[controlCenter dealloc], controlCenter = nil;
...
float timeLeft = [controlCenter timeToWaitBeforeBombDetonation];
```

This code will assign 0.0 to timeLeft which appears to be a valid wait time even though controlCenter is nil.

---

Take the above with a grain of salt, since if you are writing an Objective-C app, you are probably more concerned with keeping your users happy by avoiding crashes than destroying cities.  If the latter is a concern, you should probably be using a type-safe language like Ada.

Comment: I think so, and it is some kind of a best practice!

Comment: By "valid", I assume you mean "won't crash at this particular point". It won't "do something" (as the name implies), perhaps it should be `[obj wontDoAnything];` instead?

Comment: @Sedate Alien: It won't do anything in terms of the method not being called, but it will give you a valid return value (0, NO, etc.) if you choose to use it.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: It will give you a **a** return value, not necessarily a valid one. Perhaps `NO` should only be returned after some action is taken, etc. What about `NSZombieEnabled`? Nilling out references means it will be no help to you in debugging.

Comment: @Sedate Alien: You are correct, nilling out references can make debugging more difficult, which is why I didn't say it was a good idea.  However, sending a message to nil *will* give you a valid, predictable return value; see the link in my post.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: I don't disagree that the return value is predictable, nor that it is of the correct type. What I meant is that one might send `-[NSControlCenter timeToWaitBeforeBombDetonation:]` and get `0.0` in return from `nil`, hence detonating the bomb when it is not correct to do so. I think you should edit your post to say it isn't a good idea, because @scorpiozj seems to think it is.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy,@Sedate Alien:thank both of you. In my understanding Sedate Alien means calling a function of nil object will cause confusing result which makes debugger difficult as you don't know the "return" is valid or not. However as for the memory management I think it is a good pattern and I can't find the shortcoming. Any tips?
@titaniumdecoy:what do you mean by pointless? I believe it is safe:checking an object whether it is nil before using it and using TT_RELEASE_SAFELY if you think you will no longer use it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using these variants of "safe releases" is an expressly **bad** idea.

Your application will fail in silent and mysterious ways, as messages passed to `nil` will not raise any warnings. It's much better to not nil out your references and take advantage of all that `NSZombieEnabled` has to offer.

Comment: or.... `#define TT_RELEASE_UNSAFELY(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = (id)0x42; }`

Comment: I think we can check whether an object equals nil before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that TT_RELEASE_SAFELY sets the pointer to nil after release, so the reference won't be used after release. The pattern is a good one to follow and the TT_RELEASE_SAFELY macro makes it simpler to implement.