# If a reference is not pointing to any instance, why can the instance method still be invoked?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending a message to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil)

If a reference to `NSMutableArray` is not pointing to any object at all, because none was instantiated, why can the instance method still be invoked without any run-time error?

```
NSMutableArray *foo = nil;
NSLog(@"[null count] is %i", [foo count]);

NSLog(@"[null count] again is %i", [(NSMutableArray *) nil count]);
```

The above lines both print out `0` instead of causing a bad memory access or causing an error that says there is no instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct from *The Objective-C Programming Language:* [In Objective-C, it is valid to send a message to nil—it simply has no effect at runtime.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7)

If you read on a little further, you'll see why `[nil count]` returns `0`.