# Seems like null NSString has length 6?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a person object of class Person with property is address, age. When I check properties, I print address on screen with:

```
      NSLog(@"Add: %@, length: %i", person.address, [person.address length]);
```

The result is: **Add: nil, length: 6**

Can you explain for me why the string is null but its length shows as 6?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible..could you log %@, person and show me the output???

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting the string value of "(null)" in the field somehow, which is 6 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

What type is address? NSString I assume? use %d or %lu for length (and cast to unsigned long if using %lu) instead of %i - that should give correct result.

Length gives a NSUInteger as a result, correct string format specifier would hence be %lu although %d should also work (thinking of it, I always use %d). I never as %i...

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)string.length)
```

Look at the format specifies:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're probably looking for is: you're using the wrong string format specifier. I'm not sure what `%i` is; `%d` is for integers and `%u` for unsigned, so you need:

```
NSLog(@"Add: %@, lenght: %u", person.address, [person.address length]);
```

But... the length is possibly not returning what you think it is.

If `person.address` is `nil`, then sending the message `length` to it won't return the length (what is the length of "nothing"?). As it happens, the Objective C runtime [will return zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil) so your example "works" but is arguably not correct.