# NSString Category Method Not Getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c

The problem I am trying to solve is to convert nil strings into empty strings so I can put that as a value in `NSDictionary`.

I have the following code:

```
//Accessed in class  
prospect.title = [self.titleLabel.text emptyWhenNil];

// NSString+Additions Category

-(NSString *) emptyWhenNil
{
   if(self == nil)
      return @"";

   return self;
 }
```

But for some reason the `emptyWhenNil` method is never even invoked!! I am lost..

Comment: I did import NSString+Additions.h file. I am calling this method when the user clicks a UIButton.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is, when your string pointer is `nil`, you have no object to send that category message to. Messages to `nil` are not executed (and return `nil`) in Objective-C.

If you want to put "null" objects into a collection, such as an `NSDictionary`, or `NSArray`, you can use the `NSNull` class instead.

Alternatively you could implement this method as a class method:

```
+ (NSString *)emptyStringIfNil:(NSString *)str {
    if (!str) return @"";
    return str;
}
```

You would then call this as

```
prospect.title = [NSString emptyStringIfNil:self.titleLabel.text];
```

Comment: Not really ignored, they return `nil`, `NO` or `0`.

Comment: Yes, but certainly not executed.

Comment: Thanks @DrummerB!! Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @DrummerB Messages are never executed, they are sent. Here they are sent to `nil` which is semantically not different from sending the message to an object. The messages are not ignored and ARE executed.

Comment: @Sulthan I know Obj-C terminology (as Apple suggests), but very often people use other terminologies and talk about "calling" or "executing" methods. I don't think it's worth arguing. Btw, your first and last sentences are in direct contradiction to each other.

Comment: @DrummerB There are times when you can simplify the terminology and use the words "call" or "execute". In this case you shouldn't. However, the problem I am having is that "message to nil are not executed" is wrong. They are sent and received by `nil`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil

Comment: @Sulthan How could "nothing" be a receiver? Sending messages to `nil` is a special case. They are executed as in having a return value, but the method itself is not executed. In the question you posted, there is this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/160432/343340

Comment: It is more accurate to say that messages to nil are short-circuited by the messenger.  No methods are executed, but it the call isn't ignored.  Note that the messenger on some platforms has a hook for adding alternative mechanisms for handling messages to nil.

Answer (score 1):

If the `NSString` pointer is `nil`, the method will not be called on it, what you can do is create a static method:

```
+ (NSString *) emptyIfNil:(NSString *) str
{
    return str == nil ? @"" : str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string is nil, there is no `self` to execute the method on. The default behaviour of the runtime in this situation is to return a default nil value.

You should implement this as a static method instead. Something like this:

```
+ (NSString *)emptyStringIfNil:(NSString *)input
{
    return input ? input : @"";
}
```

Comment: Wow that's a bit verbose writing it out in full like that - `return input ?: @"";` :)

Comment: As far as I know, using `?:` with no left-hand 'then' expression is a GNU extension and will not work with all compilers.

Comment: Ok it wasn't as easy as I thought it would be to google but it's in the [API docs](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BinaryConditionalOperator.html) - `ConditionalOperator - The ?: ternary operator. The GNU "missing middle" extension is a BinaryConditionalOperator.`

Comment: It's still an extension, and not standard or portable. Some people have extensions turned off with warnings and other compiler flags. I wouldn't personally use it in a SO answer or in any library code.