# Comparing two NSNumbers using isEqualToNumber method

Tags: ios, comparison, null, nsnumber

While I compare two NSNumbers using `isEqualToNumber`, it is returning a false if both numbers are `nil`. Why a comparison of sort `[nil isEqual:nil]` always returns `false` while `nil == nil` returns `true` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the standard behaviour. You will get the same result from `isEqueslToString:` etc. It is better this way, because you could have for example `weak` references to unequal objects, which would become equal uppon deallocation.

You can use a condition like `number1.intValue == number2.intValue` in which case it would return `YES` for 2 `nil` objects. However, you will also get `YES` for `nil.intValue == @0.intValue`

Comment: I guessed it will be the default behaviour. But can you tell me what is the concept behind returning false. Its just curiosity.

Comment: It would be the source of many errors in case it would work differently, just look at the example I gave with the `weak` reference. It is like you would compare the addresses of 2 houses. If they have the same address, then you can say that these are equal. But if you take 2 houses and neither has an address, you cannot say that you were talking about the same houses. A little far-fetched comparison, but I hope you'll get the point

Comment: Thanks. Nice example. That settles my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

`[nil isEqual:nil]` compares objects while `nil == nil` compares pointers.

Pointer to nil is always equal to pointer to nil. On the other hand object that does not exist is not equal to anything.

Comment: `[nil isEqual:someObjectPointer]` sends a message to nil, which returns 0 by definition. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/156395/86436