# Error tells me that my textview is nil when trying to make NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, constraints, nsdictionary

I am about to set up some constraints in my app. When i try to make an `NSDictionary` i get the error that tells me that my `UITextView` is nil. As you can see i have set some preferences for my `UITextView`, so i would presume that it isn't nil. But, if it is nil, how to i make it not nil?

I have also tried the `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`, without any luck.

Thanks.

```
    UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:1];
    infoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    infoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [displayView addSubview:infoView];

    NSDictionary *views = @{@"infoView" : infoView};

    [displayView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[infoView]|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
    [displayView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[infoView]|"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
```

Comment: You need to `init` your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you're making is that viewWithTag: doesn't instantiate a new UIView, it just searches an existing UIView's heirarchy for another UIView that has that as its tag value. More at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:

What you need to do is instatiate your UIView first, then set its tag:

```
UIView *infoView = [[UIView alloc] init];
infoView.tag = 1;
```

Also as a side point, as surprising as it might be, setting properties (and calling methods, or sending messages) on a nil is perfectly valid in objective-c, and you can't trust it as a test that the object isn't nil. More discussion here: [Sending a message to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil)