# How Can I Get The indexpath and row in XCODE 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that used to work before I upgraded to XCODE 5.  I needed to find the row that was selected for a structure I was displaying which has over 100 rows so obviously can be scrolled on the display.  The code that used to work is:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForCell:myCell];
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
```

Now, regardless of the row selected, the value of row is always 0.  Anyone have any suggestions for me?  Thanks.

Comment: I remember that working in XCode 6 at least... you may have to provide more context...

Comment: Try indexPath.row? Probably doesn't do any difference but heck :)

Comment: Or check to see if self.table is still valid, as well as myCell

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

CGPoint pos = [pressedButton convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.mainTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mainTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pos];
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in Objective-C, you can always send a message `nil`, and methods that return something (i.e., not `void`) will return either `nil`(for an object) or `0` (for a value)  when sent to `nil` (for structs, it is more complicated; [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156395/433373)).

So make sure that:

1. `self.mainTableView` is **not** `nil`
2. `indexPath` is **not** `nil`