# iOS Crash: " this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key url"

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, crash

I am getting the following crash on crashlytics.

> Fatal Exception: NSUnknownKeyException
>       [<__NSCFString 0x1742aeb80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key url.

This is where the crash occurred for some of the users.

```
 id url = [[json[@"data"]valueForKey:@"value"]valueForKey:@"url"];
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to prevent this crash. I believe this is because `json[@"data"]` is an NSString in certain cases. So I believe I should check if this is an NSDictionary like this.

```
if ([json[@"data"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
     id url = [[json[@"data"]valueForKey:@"value"]valueForKey:@"url"];
    }
```

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

This is my end result after getting answers from here. Does this look okay? I didn't include all my code at first to keep things simple.

```
        if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            id url = nil;
            id type = nil;

            NSDictionary *data = json[@"data"];

            if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                type = data[@"type"];
                NSDictionary *value = data[@"value"];

                if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                    url = [value valueForKey:@"url"];
                }

                if ([type isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [url isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [url count] != 0) {
                   // do stuff
              }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`? Don't use key-value coding unless you have a clear, specific, and understood reason to do so.

Comment: @trungduc Does the code now look okay to you? I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CurtRand you should use `id *value` instead of `NSDictionary *value`. It makes more sense. Everything else looks good.

Comment: @CurtRand one more, i think you don't need to check `json` is kind of class `NSDictionary`. As i guess, your `json` is a `NSString` so just need to convert `json` from `NSString` to `NSDictonary`.

Comment: I have to check if 'json' is an NSDictionary because sometimes the data I get returns as a string and not a dictionary.

Comment: @CurtRand it’s up to you but you need to make sure there isn’t anything wrong if you check json is a nsdictionary value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `NSDictionary` one by one to prevent crash. Try my code below

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = json[@"data"];
NSString *output = @"";
if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
  dictionary = dictionary[@"value"];
  if ([dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    output = dictionary[@"url"];
  }
}
NSLog(@"%@", output);
```

**You got crash because of calling `valueForKey` method on a `NSString` value. If someone says the reason for crash is call `valueForKey` when dictionary doesn't have this key, it's wrong. For more information [Sending a message to nil in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156395/sending-a-message-to-nil-in-objective-c)**

[dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] always return `NO` if `dictionary` is nil so don't need to check `dictionary` in `if statement`. It's unnessary.

Answer (score -3):

Your error means that `json[@"data"]valueForKey:@"value"]` doesn't NSDictionarry, so it  have no `@"url"` key.

`valueForKey` it's KVC method, use `objectForKey` for dictionaries, and add more checks like:

```
        id url = nil;
        NSDictionary *data = [json objectForkey:@"data"];
        if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary *value = [data objectForKey:@"value"];
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                url = [value objectForKey:@"url"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: @RomanSimenok you don't need to check `data` is `nil` because `[data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]` will return `NO` if `data` is `nil` ;)

Comment: @trungduc yes i know, but what faster check if it's nil or check if it's not kind of class?)

Comment: @RomanSimenok As i guess, check `nil` will be putted on the top of method `isKindOfClass`. So don't worry about which is faster.

Comment: @RomanSimenok one more, both `valueForKey` and `objectForKey` return `nil` if if there is no object for key. His crash is because calling `valueForKey` on a `NSString`. Anw congratulation ;)

Comment: as  explained In this case the crash to call undefined method in a class....there is not much to add

Comment: ad example... 

 NSDictionary *dictionary = @{};
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"213"]);

 it will log null and without crash.