# Can't get Jacobi algorithm to work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For some reason, I can't get this program to work. I've had other CS majors look at it and they can't figure it out either.

This program performs the Jacobi algorithm (you can see step-by-step instructions and a MATLAB implementation [here](http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~gth683e/Calc3Project/projectHome.html)). BTW, it's different from the Wikipedia article of the same name.

Since `NSArray` is one-dimensional, I added a method that makes it act like a two-dimensional C array. After running the Jacobi algorithm many times, the diagonal entries in the `NSArray` (`i[0][0]`, `i[1][1]`, etc.) are supposed to get bigger and the others approach 0. For some reason though, they all increase exponentially. For instance, `i[2][4]` should equal `0.0000009`, not `9999999`, while `i[2][2]` should be big.

Thanks,

Chris

### NSArray+Matrix.m

```
@implementation NSArray (Matrix)

@dynamic offValue, transposed;

- (double)offValue {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for ( MatrixItem *item in self )
        if ( item.nonDiagonal )
            sum += pow( item.value, 2.0 );
    return sum;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)transposed {
    NSMutableArray *transpose = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
            [transpose addObject:[self objectAtRow:j andColumn:i]];
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}

- (id)objectAtRow:(NSUInteger)row andColumn:(NSUInteger)column {
    NSUInteger index = 5 * row + column;
    return [self objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)multiplyWithMatrix:(NSArray *)array {
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    double value;

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
            value = 0.0; // (JeremyP's answer)
            for ( k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
                MatrixItem *firstItem = [self objectAtRow:i andColumn:k];
                MatrixItem *secondItem = [array objectAtRow:k andColumn:j];
                value += firstItem.value * secondItem.value;
            }
            MatrixItem *item = [[MatrixItem alloc] initWithValue:value];
            item.row = i;
            item.column = j;
            [result addObject:item];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
@end
```

### Jacobi_AlgorithmAppDelegate.m

```
// ...

- (void)jacobiAlgorithmWithEntry:(MatrixItem *)entry {
    MatrixItem *b11 = [matrix objectAtRow:entry.row andColumn:entry.row];
    MatrixItem *b22 = [matrix objectAtRow:entry.column andColumn:entry.column];

    double muPlus = ( b22.value + b11.value ) / 2.0;
    muPlus += sqrt( pow((b22.value - b11.value), 2.0) + 4.0 * pow(entry.value, 2.0) );

    Vector *u1 = [[[Vector alloc] initWithX:(-1.0 * entry.value) andY:(b11.value - muPlus)] autorelease];
    [u1 normalize];
    Vector *u2 = [[[Vector alloc] initWithX:-u1.y andY:u1.x] autorelease];

    NSMutableArray *g = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for ( int i = 0; i <= 24; i++ ) {
        MatrixItem *item = [[[MatrixItem alloc] init] autorelease];
        if ( i == 6*entry.row )
            item.value = u1.x;
        else if ( i == 6*entry.column )
            item.value = u2.y;
        else if ( i == ( 5*entry.row + entry.column ) || i == ( 5*entry.column + entry.row ) )
            item.value = u1.y;
        else if ( i % 6 == 0 )
            item.value = 1.0;
        else
            item.value = 0.0;

        [g addObject:item];
    }

    NSMutableArray *firstResult = [[g.transposed multiplyWithMatrix:matrix] autorelease];

    matrix = [firstResult multiplyWithMatrix:g];
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the square root term to `muPlus`, you don't divide by two. The calculation should be either:

```
double muPlus = ( b22.value + b11.value ) / 2.0;
muPlus += sqrt( pow((b22.value - b11.value), 2.0) 
                + 4.0 * pow(entry.value, 2.0) 
              ) / 2.0;
```

or:

```
double muPlus = ( b22.value + b11.value );
muPlus += sqrt( pow((b22.value - b11.value), 2.0) 
                + 4.0 * pow(entry.value, 2.0) );
muPlus /= 2.0;
```

Also, you assign `u1.y` to both G<sub>r,c</sub> and G<sub>c,r</sub>. From the algorithm description, you want G<sub>r,c</sub>=U<sub>1,2</sub> (or `u1.y`) and G<sub>c,r</sub>=U<sub>2,1</sub> (or `u2.x`). Note that you don't actually need `u2`; you can substitute `-u1.y` for `u2.x` and `u1.x` for `u2.y`.

#### Off-Topic

According to the [Fundamental Rule of Cocoa Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), `-[NSArray multiplyWithMatrix:]` should return an autoreleased array, since the multiplicand should relinquish ownership. Also, you should use accessors to assign `GT * A * G` to `matrix` rather than doing it directly so that it can be properly managed.

Since most of the tests in the loop to fill out `g` will be false during each iteration, it's most likely more efficient to fill `g` with some default values and then update `g`. You could create a zero matrix, then set the diagonal to ones, then fill in the values from U, or you could create an identity matrix (leave the `i%6 == 0` test in the loop) then fill in the values from U. Profile each of the three approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately, I have two math finals in six hours, so I can't try out your suggestions until tomorrow afternoon. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you for your help! It completely works now! I don't know why I thought Gc,r should be set to `u1.y`. I also changed the code to start with an identity matrix and go from there. Unfortunately, it hangs after completing. I think all the `autoreleased` objects are being held until it finishes. I tried wrapping the method in an `NSAutoreleasePool` but it gets unbearably slow. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chris: you only need to autorelease objects that a method returns. Try using plain releases on `g` and the like. Don't worry too much about efficiency until you've got the algorithm working correctly.

Comment: I changed the code to `release` everything at the end of the method, but there's still a memory leak somewhere. Do you see anything else that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Chris: as the posted code no longer accurately reflects the current implementation, no. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172125/avoiding-finding-and-removing-memory-leaks-in-cocoa. If you've the time, follow Jeremy's suggestion to create a proper `Matrix` class to give yourself a firm base of abstract operations (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-14.html#%_sec_2.1.2). Using a C-style array may or may not be the best approach for your project (it's potentially the most performant, but possibly error prone), but that's not the only possible implementation.

Comment: There are probably free libraries out there that implement matrices in Objective-C.  If, however, you are interested in implementing your own matrix class, I find a C style array of doubles wrapped in an Objective-C class works pretty reliably.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got any unit tests for your matrix category?  I mean, are you certain that the multiplication algorithm works?  I would say that initialising value to 0 happens in the wrong loop.  I think you need to do it inside the j loop.

A couple of other observations:

- You don't need the `@dynamic` property declaration because you are defining the implementation of the properties yourself.
- Consider creating your own Matrix class that wraps a normal C array of doubles.  You might find the implementation a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No, I didn't have any unit tests, so I made one. You're right; moving `value = 0.0;` to the `j`-loop did fix the multiplication method. Unfortunately, the off-diagonal entries are still increasing (just not as fast). Any other ideas?