# allocating to already allocated variable in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, ios-simulator

I want to allocate memory for the variable to which i have allocated already.for example

```
        self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

I have to change assigned view controller for above tabbar controller.so i have to release
the above and allocate the same tabbar  with new controllers. how can I release and allocate 
new one.If i do the following, gives crashes in IOS5

```
  if(self.m_tabbarController != nil)
    {
      [self.m_tabbarController release];    
    }
             self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

but self variable must be deallcated in dealloc method.any help please?if i do like following also, it gives crash?

```
   m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:m_tabbarController ];
     [m_tabbarController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in .h declare "my_tabBarController",

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)my_tabBarController;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize my_tabBarController;
```

If you want to assign new view controller, just make another instance of TabbarController and assingn to existing one.

```
 TabbarController *secondTabBar=[[TabbarController alloc]init];
 self.my_tabBarController=secondTabBar;
 [secondTabBar release];
```

and dont forget to release my_tabBarController in dealloc

Answer (score -1):

For reallocating a `@property` which is of `(retain)` type, you must not release it explicitly

```
//this is wrong
if(self.m_tabbarController != nil)
    {
      [self.m_tabbarController release];    
    }
/////////////////////
```

only this line will work fine for reallocation.

```
    self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];
```

The reason is that -> for a `(retain)` property, when we do self.obj = nil or (new allocation), it means

```
[obj release];
obj = nil or (new allocation)
```

your app is crashing as `m_tabbarController` is facing a double release due to explicit and implicit release both. first time you are explicit calling release by `[self.m_tabbarController release];` and next implicit release is happening at the time of assignment `self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];`

Comment: I have allocated already for "self.m_tabbarController ".how can i do again as self.m_tabbarController = [[TabbarController alloc] init];

Comment: to backup my answer, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210776/objective-c-difference-between-setting-nil-and-releasing , you should work on your basics little more to make them even stronger. Best of luck!!