# Use of self with an instance for alloc and release

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shouldn’t I use the getter to release a property in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262268/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-getter-to-release-a-property-in-objective-c)

I am little bit confused on alloc and release with self. After looking to several post and tutorials there seems that more suggestions needed on this. Following are the list of questions:

1. Is this a correct way to alloc and release.
   self.selectPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] init];

[self.selectPopover release];

2. Trying to execute this code from another class. classArr is define in ObjClass. When i analyze this code potential leak "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller" is occured.

ObjClass.classArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[ObjClass.classArr release];

So anyone can clear my doubts on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can understand the concept you are looking for via this post:

[Objective-C Difference between setting nil and releasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210776/objective-c-difference-between-setting-nil-and-releasing)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have created the property as `retain`

when you 
`ObjClass.classArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

 At this point the retainCount becomes two, one because of `alloc` and one by assigning it through property which is of type `retain`

and when you `[ObjClass.classArr release];` at this time you send one release and the reatinCount become 1 from 2.
 So either you do like this

```
ObjClass.classArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[ObjClass.classArr release];
```

which makes its retain count to one 

 Or you can do like this which is the case which actually happens

```
   classArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

assigning ivar without property which make retainCount one.