# Does it make sense to set NSString objects to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In `viewDidUnload` where I do set the `IBOutlets` to nil, I also set the `NSString` objects to nil. These which were `(nonatomic,strong)`. Does it make sense at all to set `NSString` objects to nil?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210776/objective-c-difference-between-setting-nil-and-releasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-viewDidUnload` is meant only for releasing objects that are created in `-viewDidLoad` or `-loadView`, including IBOutlets.

If you do not allocate these strings in `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad` then it is wrong to release them in `-viewDidUnload`.

Comment: these strings are my instance variables.

Comment: what about the IButlets? are they created in "viewDidUnload" method?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you don't set any *objects* to `nil`. What you do set to `nil` is the *pointer* to one of your objects, so that it does not point to anything any more.

This means that if you have other instance variables in other objects pointing to your string, they will not see any difference in the object - they will still point to the same old string, with the same, unaltered content.

However, to answer your question: It does make  sense to `nil` out your variables, but if and when your view controller is deallocated, then the instance variables will also be deallocated. So if your strings are small, there may not be a pressing need to `nil` them out in `viewDidUnload`.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidUnload`, while it is still around, should be used to remove anything that you can re-create in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`.

If the string properties are part of your view controller's model, and can't be recreated, then don't remove them.

The method is not guaranteed to be called - it will only be called when a view controller is offscreen, but the system has come under memory pressure. It is not like `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidDisappear`. It should not be confused with your view controller's `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually managing memory then you don't have to set the outlet itself to nil, only the object linked to it.

For example, if you have `@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;`

you only need to set the image view to nil - `imageView = nil;`

Comment: ARC has nothing to do with viewDidUnload

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for calling me on that one, I don't know what I was thinking.