# What properties should I set to nil in viewDidUnload?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, didreceivememorywarning

I don't know if I'm using viewDidUnload properly. Should I release all stuff I declare in my .h file?

Here is how I'm doing it now:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Readability *wrapper;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ArticleModel *article;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Woho *wohoItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FeedItem *item;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *picturesArray;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headTitleLabel;
```

and in viewDidUnload:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setHeadTitleLabel:nil];
    [self setScrollView:nil];
    self.picturesArray = nil;
    self.item = nil;
    self.article = nil;
    self.wohoItem = nil;
    self.wrapper = nil;
}
```

Is this the right thing to do?

Probably not, because my app crash on every memory warning.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're crashing, have you turned on Zombies? What error are you getting? There's nothing obviously wrong with your `viewDidUnload`. Are all of these getting recreated in `viewDidLoad`? Is it crashing on the memory warning, or when you return to the view in question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to set NSString objects to nil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288828/does-it-make-sense-to-set-nsstring-objects-to-nil)

Comment: In addition, this question becomes irrelevant on 19 September.

Comment: viewDidUnload is deprecated in iOS 6. You should use didReceiveMemoryWarning instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a low-memory warning occurs, the `UIViewController` class purges its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including **objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy.**

Comment: So "objects create in viewDidLoad" that means every object - array, dictionary, or only uiview object? Some example would be nice

Comment: Everything you can and do recreate in `loadView`, `viewDidLoad` or that is loaded from the nib file.

Comment: By the way, see [iOS 6 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html) regarding potential changes to `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I knew that. I just have to move the code in viewDidUnload to didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: @Devfly: "I just have to move the code in viewDidUnload to didReceiveMemoryWarning." NO, for the love of God. The only things that were supposed to be in `viewDidUnload` is stuff to be done when the view is unloaded in response to low memory. Since iOS 6 no longer unloads views in low memory, whatever is in there is unnecessary. DO NOT move it somewhere else. If you need to put it somewhere else, it was in the wrong place to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

developer.apple says:

> When a view controller receives a memory warning (didReceiveMemoryWarning), it should relinquish ownership of resources that are currently not needed and that can be recreated later if required. One such resource is the view controller's view itself. If it does not have a superview, the view is disposed of (in its implementation of didReceiveMemoryWarning, UIViewController invokes [self setView:nil])

The programming guide is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6)

Set all IBOutlets to nil in - (void)viewDidUnload.
If you are using iOS 5 the better use 'weak' reference for IBOutlets.

I advise you to make Control-Drag of each iterface element from NIB(xib) or Storyboard to your interface code. It will generate all fields for you.