# Declare a retain property in class, will the compiler add [property release] to -dealloc by default?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, retain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is releasing memory of Objective-c 2.0 properties required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389162/is-releasing-memory-of-objective-c-2-0-properties-required)

For example:

```
@interface DataMode : NSObject {
    NSString * name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

Will the compiler automatically add `[name release]` to `-dealloc`?

```
- (void) dealloc
{
   [name release];    // if we  don't add it , will the compiler add "[name release]"???
   [super release];     

}
```

Comment: Note that it should be `[super dealloc]` instead of `[super release]`.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which memory management scheme you’re using:

- With garbage collection, you don’t need to release the instance variable that backs the declared property — the garbage collector automatically does that. In fact, you wouldn’t be defining a `-dealloc` method at all even if you need to do other tasks upon deallocation: the garbage collector sends `-finalize` instead of `-dealloc`;
- With automatic reference counting (ARC), you wouldn’t define that `-dealloc` method. ARC will automatically release the instance variable that backs the declared property. You can define a `-dealloc` method to do other housekeeping tasks if needed but you won’t send `[super dealloc]`;
- With manual memory management, you need to manually release the instance variable that backs the declared property and then send `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: Good summery, and I'm really anticipating changing everything to the latest technology of the three - ARC.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding or rather creating `name` its your responsibility to release it. So you need to add `[name release]` in `dealloc` and also in `ViewDidUnLoad` use `name = nil`.

ObjectiveC has garbage collection but in iOS garbage collection part has been stripped out. So allocation, deallocation, retain etc. you need to be aware of...