# Issue regarding using Leak Instrument and fixing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I have this piece of code :

```
TImageView *thumbnailView  = [[TImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
   thumbnailView.delegate = self;
    thumbnailView.hidden = NO;
    thumbnailView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    thumbnailView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    thumbnailView.urlPath = URLPath;

    [self addSubview:thumbnailView];

    [thumbnailView release];
```

`where, TImageView is a custom class`

Now, when using the leaks instrument, for one instance, one leak, if I click on the extended detail,

I see that 99.6% of memory leakage is because of this line:

```
    thumbnailView.urlPath = URLPath;
```

I have got no clue. Any help ?

Comment: can u give us the code, where URLPath (by convention better urlPath) is created. and how does TImageView's urlPath property look like.

Comment: What do u mean with private class?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: 1. sorry, meant custom class. 2. URLPath is a NSString.

Comment: The string doesn't seem to be released/autoreleased

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons:

1. You're not releasing urlPath attribute (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389162/is-releasing-memory-of-objective-c-2-0-properties-required))
2. You're not releasing URLPath (don't use such names!)

Comment: 2. URLPath is something I get from the method argument. (I did not write this custom class....)