# Dot notation dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

```
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *orbit;
@property (copy) NSNumber *mass;
@property float surfaceTemp;
@property float rotationSpeed;
```

Currently Have this

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [name release];
    name = nil;
    [orbit release];
    orbit = nil;
    [mass release];
    mass = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

If I write this using Dot Notation (Objective-C 2.0) Is this right?

```
- (void)dealloc{
    self.name = nil;
    self.orbit = nil;
    self.mass = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

gary

Comment: Small tip: you can cut down on the number of lines of code in your `dealloc` method by doing something like this: `[name release], name=nil;`. Just a small formatting thing, but I think it's easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I shall use that, much appreciated.

Comment: There's not really a need to nil out an ivar during a dealloc. Logically, you're setting the value of a variable an object which you already know is about to be destroyed. There's an argument to be made there for consistencies sake with the rest of your code I guess. 

One reasonable way to do this is a release macro, like this:

#define TT_RELEASE(__P) { [__P release]; __P = nil; }

Comment: Not nilling out ivars during dealloc is the #1 reason using accessors in dealloc is dangerous – a subclass may have left an ivar dangling, and then try to access it in an overridden setter. Still, leaving them dangling is the long-standing Cocoa norm, so it can’t really be said to be wrong. Personally, I’ve started adapting the GNUstep style of using a DESTROY() macro to release and clear variables in one go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's bad practice to use your setter methods in `-dealloc`. Use `[name release]` instead.

Calling setters during `-dealloc` may have unintended consequences.  If using KVO, setting properties may trigger other code to run causing side effects because your object has already started releasing instance variables. Even when not using KVO this may cause potential problems if your setter method relies on other instance variables that may have already been released.

(updated to reflect comments)

Comment: I'd read this before, but only with respect to using them init, due to a potentially partially-initialized object. Why are they bad to use in dealloc?

Comment: I've been searching for the reference, but to be honest I'm not sure why this is frowned upon.  I just know that I was corrected because I used to do the same thing.  The only thing I can think of is that your setter method may depend on other ivars or properties that have already been released.

Comment: @nall if you have other objects using KVO to observe changes to that object's properties, then using the accessors in a dealloc can cause interesting things to happen (like the observers attempting to manipulate a partially destructed object). More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283419

Comment: Oh, duh. Same basic argument as init. Thx.

Comment: Interesting, whats KVO if I might ask? But many thanks for your comments, I will take that as maybe its not such a good idea.

Comment: It's a mechanism for being notified when variables you specify change. More here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Not necessarily variables, but properties. The property can be backed by anything, including an instance variable, a key in a dictionary, a row in a database, or a file on disk. One of the purposes of accessors is to insulate users (and observers) of the property from your implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience `self.name = nil` does not do the same thing as `[name release]; name = nil`. My guess is that there is some code in the synthesized setter that avoids `nil` assignments, but YMMV. The properties I observed this on were also specified `(nonatomic, retain)` so you might see some differences there, too.

What is more, `self.` notation sends KVO notifications, so there is a performance penalty to be considered in this case as well.

Comment: Interesting, do you know if there is an overhead when using this notation in main() i.e. if you were accessing obj.name = @"mr happy"; as apposed to the more traditional [obj setName: @"mr happy"];

Comment: The use cases you mentioned are the equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure if they add a performance penalty- that would depend on the implementation. What I can tell you is that `self.x = ...` and `[self setX:...]` invoke the same code, which will incur the same penalty. Or did you have a different question in mind?