# Which should I use: self.property or _property

Tags: objective-c

I'm sorry I do not know Objective-C well.

Here is *SomeClass.h* :

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

@property NSString *property;

@end
```

We can use `property` in *SomeClass.m* as both

`self.property`

and

`_property`.

Which should I use?

Is there some situation to decide which way to use?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don't know, use self.property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically in standard practice, you only ever use `_property` in a getter/setter/init/dealloc method. In all other cases you use `self.property` or `[self property]`

#### Why?

Using `_property` is strictly used to assign or get a value directly, while using self.property is the same as calling [self property].

In this way, you can create custom getters/setters for the method that all classes are required to abide by when they use this variable, **including the class holding the variable itself**.

#### For example:

If I call `object.property`, I am essentially calling `[object property]`. Now this doesn't matter so much if you don't define custom methods, but if you have a custom getter or setter method in your object's class:

```
- (Type)property{
    return 2*_property;
}

//AND/OR

- (void)setProperty:(Type)property
{
    _property = 2*property;
}
```

Then there will be a difference between using `_property` and `self.property`.

Make sense?

Comment: You should also use direct access in `init` and `dealloc`. See [here](http://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-init/), [here](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide/issues/6) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1286227/1489997)

Answer (score 0):

`self.property` calls the (generated) getter; equivalent to `[self property]`.

`_property` accesses the variable directly.

[The general recommendation](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774?mt=10) is to use `self.property`, since the getter may be overridden to do something special, such as extra memory management, or lazy creation, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.property`.
If you have specific reasons to ignore the setter of this property, use `_property`.