# Is it "bad" to use @properties for private variables just for the memory management benefits?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Is it bad to create @properties for private variables just for the memory management benefits?

It seems messy and wrong to have public facing @properties for many private variables.

(Mainly, I am releasing private ivars during low memory conditions using the respective "event" methods.)

**Example:**
I usually do this to release a private ivar:

```
[name release]; name = nil;
```

But with @properties, I can do this:

```
self.name = nil;
```

Later in my code, will do this, hence the need to set to nil:

```
if( !name)
    name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hi %@",inputName];
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An alternative is to keep the property private. You can use the following code (in your .m file) to make the property only accessible within your class:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass ()
    @property (retain) NSString* privateString; 
@end

@implementation MyClass

    @synthesize privateString;
    // Your code here

@end
```

Now you've got the ease of a property, but other classes still can't access it, even if they import your .h file!

Comment: This is great, but it seems like a hack.  I'm not sure I'm going to do this in my code, but at least I know there is an alternative to what I'm doing now.   Thank you!!

Comment: Its not a hack, it is an explicit form of Category called an Extension. <https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2>.  "It is common for a class to have a publicly declared API and to then have additional API declared privately for use solely by the class or the framework within which the class resides"

Comment: It is absolutely not a hack and is 100% in line with why class extensions were added to the language in the first place. Embrace this pattern with gusto.

Comment: Got it.  I will start using this then.

Comment: You now have the benefit now that calls to privateString will now cause a compiler warning.  However if you ignore them and call from another class [myClassInstance privateString] the program will respond to the selector and will not trigger an error.

Answer (score 2):

Properties exist for your convenience.  If you don't want other people to use properties that exist in your classes, just don't document them.

Comment: But they are visible in your .h file.  andyvn22 has a alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

For public properties I don't think Apple recommends it, because sometimes setting a property to nil can have side effects other than just releasing the variable (KVO notifications, or a custom setter method that does something else).

As for private properties, I'm not too sure. Using a property will only save you a couple of key strokes while coding, but you're also making it slightly more complex and fragile. I favour readability and maintainability over convenience to write, because you'll save time in the long run.

Comment: Quote from apple documentation in UIViewController Class reference for method - (void)viewDidUnload: 

"The preferred way to relinquish ownership of any object (including those in outlets) is to use the corresponding accessor method to set the value of the object to nil"

Comment: I looked around to find the original reason why I thought it was bad (because I forgot), and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-obective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc . It seems that it's only a concern in init or dealloc.