# Is it not safe to call Accessor methods in init and dealloc methods in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Is it not safe to call Accessor methods in init and dealloc methods in Objective C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc)

Comment: @zoul: I agree it is a duplicate but the accepted answer is not a complete explanation.  All it says is that "nasty things might happen", which is not satisfactory.  For this reason, I'm not voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the setters. Some may be safe to call, some not. The problem is you can’t be sure which are, since subclasses can override them. If a subclass overrides a setter you use in `-init` you’re calling it before the subclass is fully initialized which is a potentially unsafe operation.

You may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc).

Comment: There's also the issue that in dealloc, you might be using a subclass accessor after the subclass state has been torn down.  There's also the issue that using a setter in dealloc will trigger any KVO notifications set which you almost certainly don't want.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a problem though not sure why you would want to call accessors in init or dealloc. Also you don't really need to call accessors since you are in an instance method and can reference the variables directly.

Comment: you would commonly call a setter during init if the setter did some non-trivial operation beyond updating the value of an ivar