# memory management and instance variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Usually when I create an object and assign it to an instance variable I alloc a temp object, call the iVar setter to retain the object and then release the temp object. However I was looking at init this morning and noticed that if I simply assign the iVar directly, its retained by the alloc whilst also being released correctly when either the setter is called or dealloc is executed. I am just curious if I am understand this correctly?

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

.

```
@synthesize locationManager;

// VERSION 001
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        CLLocationManager *tempManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self setLocationManager:tempManager];
        [tempManager release];  
    }
    return self;
}

// VERSION 002
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 002 is the Apple approved answer because the pitfalls of using an accessor in init are theoretically worse.  Basically, a subclass could choose to override your accessor and then you'd be sending a message to a subclass object that is not yet initialised.

However, everywhere else except init and dealloc, use version 001.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the memory management goes both solutions are fine. But you might want to prefer the direct access in `init` and `dealloc`, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721).

Comment: I was aware of not using setters in dealloc from a previous question, its good to know that I should not be using them in init as well. So would I be right in saying that for init & delloc directly assign the iVars like v_002. For other methods its best to go with alloc object, use the setter to assign the iVar & finally release the object.