# Have trouble appending to an NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

```
@interface MainView : UIView { 
    NSMutableString *mutableString; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *mutableString;
@end

@implementation MainView
@synthesize mutableString;

-(void) InitFunc {  
    self.mutableString=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 }

-(void) AppendFunc:(*NString) alpha { 
    [self.mutableString stringByAppendingString:@"hello"];
    NSLog(@"the appended String is: %@",self.mutableString);
    int len=[self.mutableString length];
}
```

Hey Everyone,

i just want to know where I am doing wrong ??? . I tried this code but "mutableString" does not append any value (as value of "len"comes '0' and NSLog doesnt print any value for "mutableString"), though i ve searched on net for the solution, people implemented in the same fashion yet i dont know why my code isnt working.

Thanks in Advance

MGD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringByAppendingString:` creates new string. Use `appendString:` instead:

[mutableString appendString:@"hello"]

Answer (score 3):

1) Your method names violate the naming conventions: use lower case letters to start with.

2) `stringByAppendingString` returns a new string as a result and doesn't modify your original. You should use `[self.mutableString appendString:@"hello"];` instead.

3) Your init method is leaking. You should use `mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];` and not use the dot syntax, as it will be `retain`ed otherwise (and a `release` would be missing).

Comment: Thanks Brother, Problem Solved!, Actually I am new into it and i need good guidance from the experienced people like u :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh God, what a mess. The `stringByAppendingString` does not change the string, it creates and returns a new one:

```
// Sets str2 to “hello, world”, does not change str1.
NSMutableString *str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"hello, "];
NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByAppendingString:@"world"];
```

If you want to change the mutable string itself, use the `appendString` method:

```
// Does not return anything, changes str1 in place.
[str1 appendString:@"world"];
```

Also, this is a leak:

```
self.mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

This is best written as:

```
mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

…because using accessors in `init` and `dealloc` [is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721).

Comment: oooopsss yeahhhhh :$ ... m sorry i ve posted such a stupid question btw thanks for help

Comment: It’s not a stupid question and there’s nothing wrong with writing a messy code, we have all been through that. (Hell, I *still* write messy code.) Just try to get a little better all the time, that’s all.

Comment: thank you very much ... ill keep ur valuable advice with me :)