# Question about how objective c property setters work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

Are my two assumptions about properties correct?

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
NSDate *Created;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *Created;

@end

@implementation Foo

@synthesize Created;

- (id) init {
if(self = [super init])
{
    Created = [NSDate date]; //this will not call the setter and instead just access the variable directly, which means it will not automatically get retained for me.
    self.Created = [NSDate date]; // this will call the setter, which will retain the variable automatically for me.
}
return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [Created release]   
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes;  that is correct.

Note that the instance variable should be `created`; it should start with a lowercase letter.  I'd also recommend `creationDate`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended not to use properties in dealloc or init, so in the init method instead of doing `self.propertyName = [NSDate date];` you should do `fieldName = [[NSDate alloc] init];` the release in dealloc is fine though

[More about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc)

Comment: I don't buy the "don't use properties in init" stuff.  I use "retain" properties specifically so I don't have to pay such close attention to retains/releases.   Whenever I try to "optimize" by using raw ivar references I invariably end up with a retain/release bug.    I don't use custom setters/getters, just the default @synthesize, which is perfectly fine for use in init.

Comment: When the only places you use the ivar references are init and dealloc it's not that easy to screw something up. I don't use it for optimization but simply because that's what apple recommends.