# Memory leak in objective-c class init method

Tags: objective-c, class, memory-management, initialization, memory-leaks

I'm having problems with a leak in the `init` method of a class I have created.  To keep it simple, I have the following (simplified) problem:

- ViewController initialises an instance of
- ClipData class which initialises an instance of
- AnimationData class which initialise a string

ViewController:

```
myClipData = [[ClipData alloc] init];
```

ClipData:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        animData = [[AnimationData alloc] init];  //LEAK HERE
    }

    return self;
}
```

AnimationData:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        name = [NSString string];
    }

    return self;
}
```

All the objects in the classes are declared as `(nonatomic, retain)`.  I'm aware that doing this bumps up the retain count, but how do I initialise the `AnimationData` without leaking the `animData`???

Probably a very stupid question, so any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Duncs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never releasing the animData. You need to add `dealloc` to your class:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [animData release];

  [super dealloc];
}
```

Similarly, you need to add a similar `dealloc` to `AnimationData`.

On a related note, you need to retain and later release the string created in `-[AnimationData init]`, what you are doing right now is essentially a noop, except that it leaves behind a garbled pointer.

Comment: Actually, thanks to ann implementation detail of Cocoa, he is lucky with the `[NSString string]` method since it returns a reference to a constant (empty) string that never goes away.

Comment: @JeremyP: Be that as it may, it's not behavior you should come to rely on.

Comment: No it's not and I did not mean to imply that you should rely on it.  I was just adding the point to explain why theDuncs won't actually see a garbage string as a result of this, using the current implementation of Cocoa.

Comment: Huge school-boy error on my part. I think I still have some unresolved questions in my head about memory allocation, but now I get this part.  Thanks WT.  You da man!

Answer (score 0):

When you have an alloc you must also have a release.

You should also reference the properties through self so you access the properties rather than the underlying members.

So you should really do :

```
ClipData *clip = [[ClipData alloc] init];
self.myClipData = clip;
[clip release];
```

And

```
 if (self) {
        AnimationData *data = [[AnimationData alloc] init]; 
        self.animData = data;  
        [data release];
    }
```

Make sure you also release the properties in the dealloc of the class by setting them to nil.

```
self.myClipData = nil;
self.animData = nil;
```

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc

Comment: Mongus - thanks so much. I'm not sure I understand the benefit of assigning the new ClipData to an object, then releasing the object.  Surely I can just call self.myClipData = [[ClipData alloc] init];  ???  I managed to resolve the leak by using the dealloc method, which I'd forgotten to add, but the points go to Williham for getting there first.  Thanks so much!

Comment: The alloc will give the object a reference count of 1. Assigning it to the property - which retains the object - will increase the count to 2. So you need a release to set the count back to 1. In your question you are not assigning via the property, so you are avoiding the extra retain.

Comment: I like to see allocs and releases close together to avoid confusion.