# How to avoid memory leaks in Cocos2d for iOS on class properties

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I have cocos2d class which produces memory leak if I do not release autoreleased object (self.graphicsContainer). Code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCNode * graphicsContainer; // I create property

@synthesize graphicsContainer = _graphicsContainer; // I synthesize it

-(id)init 
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.graphicsContainer = [CCNode node]; // which returns autoreleased object!
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc 
{
    [self.graphicsContainer release]; // If I do not release it I get memory leak warning!
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Anyone knows why I have to release it? As far as I know I shouldn't release autoreleased objects?

Comment: Is this code running on a background thread?

Comment: This code is inside inside init of main layer and main scene. No threads ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the behavior I'd expect from that code.  Because graphicsContainer is a retained property, the line

```
self.graphicsContainer = [CCNode node]; // which returns autoreleased object!
```

...will retain the the node, so you need to release it in dealloc as you're doing.  There's basically nothing wrong with what you're doing there.

One caveat: it's perhaps controversial, but for various reasons, it's generally frowned upon to use property accessors in init and dealloc.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc) has more information on that (even better: read [Mike Ash's excellent analysis](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html) of the subject).

If you fall into the 'property accessors in init/dealloc is bad' camp (I do), you could change it to this:

```
-(id)init 
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _graphicsContainer = [[CCNode node] retain]; // which returns autoreleased object!
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc 
{
    [_graphicsContainer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The code above is exactly equivalent to what you're doing, except that it's not calling the property accessors.