# NSDate as @property give me bad_exc_access

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

i want initialize a nsdate with a specific date, to use it in all my code an i'm doing this:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *myDate;
```

.m

```
@synthesize myDate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

        myDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2050-01-01"];
    } 
    return self;
}
```

then in the code, if i read that nsdate like in this way:

```
NSLog(@"%@",myDate);
```

or if i use isEqualToDate, give me a exc_bad_access

why?

Comment: Note the perils of using accessors in `init...` methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the variable as a property, you need to invoke it as

```
self.myDate = [formatter dateFromString:"2050-01-01"];
```

Otherwise, it is just doing a straight assign to the variable storing it behind.  When you declare a property as `retain` within the automatically generated `setMyDate` function that is invoked when you use `self.myDate = someDate;` a call to `retain` on the object passed in is made in order to hold onto the object.

In general, it is considered a best practice to only access your properties through the automatically generated methods, or through `self.myDate` method to ensure proper use of reference counting functions

Comment: Instead of using self.myDate, synthesizes properties can automatically create an ivar.  @synthesize myDate = _myDate; and then use _myDate = [formatter dateFromString:...];

Comment: He would still need to call `retain` on the object returned from `dateFromString` or it will be autoreleased at the end of the init function