# Avoid Memory Leak When Property Assigning Twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, properties, memory-leaks

Let say i have an class named as **MyTestClass.h**.

Class structure is look like

```
@interface MyTestClass : NSObject {

    NSString *testString;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString * testString;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@implementation MyTestClass

@synthesize testString;    

-(id) init{ 

    [self setTestString:@""];           
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{ 

    [self.testString release];      
    testString = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now i created an object of **MyTestClass** and assigned **testString** twice

```
MyTestClass * myTestClass = [[MyTestClass alloc] init];

[myTestClass setTestString:@"Hi"];
[myTestClass setTestString:@"Hello"];
```

Now i think, two times my testStrings memory is leaked!! (one through **init()** and another one through my first **setTestString** method)

Am i correct? or will `@property (nonatomic, retain)` handle/release previous allocated memory?

or ,in this kind of cases ,will i need to override the **setTestString()** in *MyTestClass.m* like below code

```
-(void)setTestString:(NSString *)tempString{    

    [testString release];
    testString = nil;

   testString = [tempString retain];
}
```

Any help on this question is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't leaking any that I can see - although I use ARC. To my knowledge, you'd only be leaking in this situation if you created an assignment variable and then didn't release it before your method ended.

Comment: Note that your `dealloc` method could also be simplified to `self.testString = nil;` before the call to `super`, which will use the auto-generated setter automatically release the previous value of testString.

Comment: apple documentation specifically states not to use accessors in the init and dealloc methods.  was hoping to quote documentation but cant find it at the moment, this will have to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc

Comment: you mean that just writing " @property (nonatomic, retain)NSString * testString;" and "@synthesize testString;" will automatically handle all the memory management.. am right? if no, then where i release the properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any help on this question is appreciated.

I'll take this as a licence to make sone observations not necessarily directly related to your question.

Firstly, if you declare a retain property (as you have done) and synthesize it, the automatically generated getters and setters handle memory management correctly for you.

If you manually create  setter (which you are allowed to do even with an `@synthesize` existing), you have to do the memory management yourself.  Use either of trojanfoe's examples.

The setter in your question contains a bug in that if testString == tempString i.e. you assign the value of the property to itself, you could end up with assigning a dangling pointer to the property because you effectively release tempString and then retain it.

---

This is an implementation detail that you an safely ignore, but string literals e.g. `@"blah"` are compiled into the executable and will never be deallocated no matter how many times they are released. So, with your example, even if the setter did not do correct memory management, there will be no leak.

---

By the way, the normal pattern for an init method is

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        // init stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

or logical equivalent.

You should get into the habit of using it because you need to call the super class's init method and it is allowed to change the value of self, even to nil.

Also, while it is very good practice normally to set the object reference to nil after releasing it, in both cases when you do it, it is unnecessary.  the first time, the variable is about to go out of scope and the second time you immediately assign it from some other object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a leak. Synthesized variable are correctly handled.

A synthesized method is implemented in this way (for a retain keyword)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string;
//backed by variable NSString *_string;

- (void)setString:(NSString*)newString
{
    if (newString != _string) {
       [_string release];
       _string = [newString retain];
    }
}
```

Of course this is a leak:

```
- (void)aMethod //of my class with string property
{
   NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
   self.string = aString; //retain count of 2
   self.string = @"hello2"; //retain count of 1 for aString

  //now I don't release aString.... leak

}
```

Comment: is your mentioned that @property (nonatomic, retain) will handle/release previous allocated memory. i dont want to implenet the setTestString method. am i right?

Comment: Yes.. you don't need to implement it. I did it only to show you how it is implemented the method (and how it was implemented before the introduction of properties...)... so.. simply write the couple `@property` and `@synthesize` and you are ok!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the auto-generated setter (in your case, `setTestString:`, which is also called by `self.testString = ...;`), the previous value of a `retain` property is released before being set.  So no, there is no leak in the code you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

The `synthesize`d setter method should do the right thing.  Here's an example of it's implementation:

```
- (void)setTestString:(NSString *)tempString
{    
    [tempString retain];
    [testString release];
    testString = tempString;
}
```

or:

```
- (void)setTestString:(NSString *)tempString
{    
    if (tempString != testString)
    {
        [testString release];
        [tempString retain];
        testString = tempString;
    }
}
```

Comment: The one that's actually used is the bottom one.  Either is valid, but the bottom one gives you a marginal performance benefit since no expensive retains and releases are done if tempString == testString.

Comment: is your mentioned that @property (nonatomic, retain) will not handle/release previous allocated memory. i have to implement the setTestString method to mange memory. am i right?

Comment: @Ramshad No, using the `retain` property attribute generates code similar to the methods I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

the dealloc is only called when the instance is destructed.
if you do :

```
[myTestClass setTestString:@"Hi"];
[myTestClass setTestString:@"Hello"];
```

in the same block, you're juste calling twice the setter. there is no memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@synthesize` on a property that specifies `retain`, the setter that's generated will handle the retain/release correctly for multiple assignments.  As long as you use `self.` rather than going directly to the backing variable and do a final release in `dealloc` you should be fine.