# Init Not Returning Self

Tags: objective-c, xcode, initialization

I have my default initialiser:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {   
    }

    return self;
}
```

I have only included this method in my class to track whether it was performing it's job, and from what I can tell, it is.

Self is getting set,and in the console I can see that self has a memory address which is not 0x0000000. For example, here is the console from a run I just tried:

```
self    IssueManager *  0x08383ad0
```

However, when the method returns self to this method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

        if (self)
            self.issueManager                           = [[IssueManager alloc] init];

        return self;
    }
```

self.issueManager remains an empty pointer:

```
_issueManager   IssueManager *  0x00000000
```

I have no idea why this is the case, but would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can we see where you declare IssueManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
self.issueManager
```

try:

```
issueManager = [[IssueManager alloc] init];
```

Remember, using the dot notation is simply using the accessor/setter methods provided by @property and @synthesize. In your init method, you should not use accessor/setter methods.

Comment: I removed the self.issueManager and replaced it with _issueManager.
The IDE then warned me that assigning this to a weak pointer would mean that by the end of the function it would have been set to nil already.

Therefore, I did what you said, but also made it a strong pointer. This has fixed the problem.

In 4 minutes I will accept your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use an accessor in `-init*` (read this: [Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc))

There is an Apple statement on this as well.

Try to do instead:

```
_issueManager = [[IssueManager alloc] init];
```