# Object ownership in stringWithString and initWithString in NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I understand that any init... method initializes a new object and that NSString stringWithString makes a copy of the parameter string as a new object. I also understand that being the objects' owner, I can control the release/deallocation of any objects that I allocate. What I don't understand is when would I use the stringWithString method since any local variable assigned that way would have it's memory "owned" by NSString instead of the local class.

The "Programming in Objective C" book by Kochan (1st ed) uses the following code (see pages 342-344) to explain that the initWithString is preferable to stringWithString because the AddressCard class would own the name variable contents. Also, I don't get any errors making repeated calls to the setName version with the stringWithString method. TIA!!

```
//header file has appropriate declarations but not included here:
#import "AddressCard.h"

@implementation AddressCard;

-(NSString *) name
{
   return name;
}

//Recommended code:
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   [name release]
   name = [[NSString alloc] initWthString: theName];
}

//Incorrect code according to Kochan:
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   [name release]
   name = [NSString stringWthString: theName];
}

//rest of class implementation code snipped
@end
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What I don't understand is when would I use the stringWithString method since any local variable assigned that way would have it's memory "owned" by NSString instead of the local class.

That's not correct.

Object ownership is determined by five rules, based on the name of the method you get an object from:

- Any object returned by `alloc`, `copy`, `copyWithZone`, or `new` has a retain count of 1.
- `retain` increases the receiving object's retain count.
- `release` decreases the receiving object's retain count.
- `autorelease` tells the current autorelease pool to send the receiving object the `release` message “later”.
- Any factory method that doesn't have “new” or “copy” in the name (e.g., `stringWithString:`) returns an object that it has autoreleased on your behalf.

Or, digested a bit:

- Any method whose name contains `copy`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `new` returns an object that you own.
- Any method that doesn't, returns an object that you don't own.
- To own an object, retain it.

The incorrect implementation of `setName:` that you show is incorrect because it stores an autoreleased object in an instance variable, when you mean to own the object. You should retain it or, in this case, copy it. One way is to simply use `alloc` and `initWithString:`, as in the correct example you show; the other way would be `copy`.

[The Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa explains everything.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) Every Cocoa or Cocoa Touch programmer should read or re-read it from time to time.

Comment: So, this means if I `retain` any object then I need to `release` it. In other words; if I `alloc` the object then I need `release` it anyway, but if I retain it before `release` once. How many times do I need to `release`?

Comment: @Mohammad Abdurraafay: If you `alloc` it and then `retain` it, you own it twice, so you need to `release` it twice.

Comment: my question is, if I make a copy of the argument by **alloc** and **initWithString** (then I **own** it), and thus I should override the dealloc method and release it myself?

Comment: @shiyingyu: That's correct. The same is true if you make a copy of the argument by sending it `copy`. Either way, you own the copy and must release it.

Comment: Seeing your edit brings up fond memories. But thankfully this all became moot over a decade ago when we switched to ARC.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, both setters are wrong.  The 'incorrect' one is wrong for general memory management reasons (which are well-expounded elsewhere).  The 'recommended' one is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. if (theName == name), then you're
   likely to deallocate your object in
   the first line, and then attempt to
   use the deallocated object as a
   parameter to -initWithString: on the
   second line, resulting in undefined
   behavior.
2. -initWithString: does not handle being passed nil gracefully.

The 'correct' (IMHO) method is:

```
-(void) setName: (NSString *) theName
{
   if (theName == name) return; // if they're equal, no need to do anything further
   [name release];
   name = [theName copy];  // sets name to nil if theName is nil
}
```

For most objects you'll actually want to -retain instead of -copy on that third line, but for strings it's almost always better to copy.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between initWithString and stringWithString is that stringWithString returns an auto-released pointer. This means that you don't need to release it specifically, since that will be taken care of next time that the auto-release pool cleans up any auto-released pointers.

initWithString, on the other hand, returns a pointer with a retain count of 1 - you do need to call release on that pointer, or else it would result in a memory leak.

See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193288/what-is-the-cost-of-using-autorelease-in-cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193288/what-is-the-cost-of-using-autorelease-in-cocoa#193377) for some reasons as why you should use auto-release vs release.

Comment: More precisely, initWithString: does not change the retain count, whereas stringWithString: returns an object whose retain count will decrease by 1 later.

Answer (score 0):

In the Incorrect code above, the next time name is referenced after setName is called, you'll get an exception error, since the object will have been released. You can use either the "Correct" code, or wrap your stringWithString call in an explicit retain call:

```
name = [[NSString stringWithString: theName] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is when would I use the stringWithString method since any local variable assigned that way would have it's memory "owned" by NSString instead of the local class.

A string created with `stringWithString:` isn't owned by the `NSString`, it is owned by the `NSAutoreleasePool` (although multiple places can `retain` an object, making ownership shared).

With `stringWithString:`, the string will become invalid when the autorelease pool is next processed (normally during the application's next event loop) because the NSAutoreleasePool will `release` its pointer. If you have not `retain`ed the string before then, any pointer you have to it (`name` in the case of your class) will be invalid (the variable `name` will still exist but it will point to garbage).

Autorelease is good, if you don't intend to keep any pointers to the `NSString` but since you do intend to keep a pointer, you'll need to `retain` the `NSString`. `initWithString:` gives you a retain count of 1 automatically.