# copy one NSString to another

Tags: iphone, nsstring, copy, copywithzone

How to copy one NSString to another?

```
@interface MyData : NSObject
{
    @private

    //user's private info
    NSInteger uID;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *surname;
    NSString *email;
    NSString *telephone;

    //user's picture
    UIImage *image;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int uID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *surname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *telephone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

I have two objects of this type. MyData *obj1, obj2;

First is initialized. Second I want to initialize with first.

```
obj2 = [obj1 copy];   //crashes

    newData.surname = data.surname;   //crashes to
    newData.email = data.email;
    newData.telephone = data.telephone;
```

I neeeeed a COPY of second object NOT RETAIN!!! Help please! Thanx!

Comment: Is obj2 actually a MyData *? You need MyData *obj1, *obj2;

Comment: yes. This variables of equal type!

Comment: MyData *obj1, *obj2;   I just forgotten asterix.

Comment: So do you want to copy the NSString or the MyData?

Comment: I want to copy MyData, but I want that fields in different objects will have different addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your object should probably implement the copy itself:

```
@implementation MyData

-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    MyData *obj = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    obj.uID = self.uId;
    obj.name = self.name
    ...
    return obj;
}

....
@end
```

Comment: Objects has defferent addresses but!!!! NSString object has EQUAL addresses. I need differrent addresses.

Comment: then you should copy them, using
    obj.name = [self.name copy]
and so on

Comment: if you need a different address, you must create it yourself. Allocate your NSzone zone and then use it your copy obj2 = [obj1 copyWithZone:zone], and propagate in the copy method:

    -(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{ 
    ... obj.name = [self.name copyWithZone:zone] ...
    }

Comment: @ Romain previous comment: "obj.name = [self.name copyWithZone:zone]" this is a memory leak

Answer (score 5):

you can use the NSString method [stringWithString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

See [also stringwithstring, what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616348/nsstring-stringwithstring-whats-the-point) to understand when this might be preferred to simply giving it the same string.

Answer (score 2):

Change your @property's to use copy instead of retain:

```
@property (nonatomic) int uID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *surname;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *telephone;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *image;
```

Note that you also don't need the assign for the uID.  Just leave that part out.  Then you can easily create a copy by alloc and init-ing a second MyData object and assigning the properties :

```
MyData data = [[MyData alloc] init];
newData.surname = data.surname;   
newData.email = data.email;
newData.telephone = data.telephone;
```

Comment: This variant not recommended in my situation.