# Creating a long NSString causing memory issues

Tags: iphone, nsstring

My code below is causing my app to quit i.e. get black screen and then see in debugger console: Program received signal:  “0”.

Basically it is causing problem when my orderArray has count of 2000 or more. I am using iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.2

Question: Is there a more efficient and less memory consuming way to create my long outStr?

```
NSString *outStr = @"";

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].orderArray objectAtIndex:i];
    outStr = [outStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@\n", 
              [dict valueForKey:@"CODE"], 
              [dict valueForKey:@"QTY"],
              [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].descDict valueForKey:[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]],
              [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].priceDict valueForKey:[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]]];

}
```

Update: Thanks to very kind people who helped, below is my modified code:

```
NSArray *orderA = [ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].orderArray;
NSDictionary *descD = [ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].descDict;
NSDictionary *priceD = [ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].priceDict;
NSMutableString *outStr = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
for (int i = 0; i < [orderA count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [orderA objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *code = [dict valueForKey:@"CODE"];
    [outStr appendFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@\n", 
              code, 
              [dict valueForKey:@"QTY"],
              [descD valueForKey:code],
              [priceD valueForKey:code]];
}


[self emailTxtFile:[NSString stringWithString:outStr]];
```

// This reaches end of method

Comment: Looks good, although you can drop the `[NSArray arrayWithArray:...]`, `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:...]` things. I.e. `NSArray *orderA = [ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].orderArray;` will do fine and consume less memory.

Comment: you are retrieving `[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]` three times per iteration, maybe once is enough?

Comment: ok let me try updating again. the reason i have been accessing data from app delegates a lot because it seems like a short cut to access data "globally". i know it's a very bad habit.

Comment: sometimes it's a fine solution. But you could still do `[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]` once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that in every iteration a new string object is formed. This consumes a lot of memory. One solution could be to use a local autoreleasepool, but that's rather complicated here.

You should use an `NSMutableString`, like:

```
NSMutableString *outStr = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].orderArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [outStr appendFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@\n", 
          [dict valueForKey:@"CODE"], 
          [dict valueForKey:@"QTY"],
          [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].descDict valueForKey:[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]],
          [[ARAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].priceDict valueForKey:[dict valueForKey:@"CODE"]]];
}
```

Then you can use `outStr`, just as if it was an `NSString`. As Tom points out in the comments, you could turn the `NSMutableString` into an `NSString` when you're finished, using:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithString:outStr];

[outStr release]; // <-- add this line and remove the autorelease
                  //     from the outStr alloc/init line
```

making your code re-usable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Great answer. For more safety, its better to return a 'real' NSString, so  realOut = [NSString stringWithString:outStr] will prevent you from making mistakes in the future.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616348/nsstring-stringwithstring-whats-the-point

Comment: good point. And for more speed, get `orderArray`, `descDict` and `priceDict` once, before you enter the loop.

Comment: Thank you all! I am testing the change and so far so good. After the above code I am calling a method [self emailTxtFile:[NSString stringWithString:outStr]]; Is that good enough? Should I release outStr inside that method when I finish using it?

Comment: Also, @mvds, when you suggest get orderArray,descDict,priceDict once, do you mean creating a local version before the loop? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Nononono don't do that! You only release what you create. Period. Elaborating: "create" means `alloc`/`copy`/`new`, "release" can be `release` or `autorelease`. We see *one* `alloc`, so we do *one* `autorelease`, within the same scope (i.e. function in this case)

Comment: @topace: yes indeed. You don't want to repeat things that always have the same end result, like getting the `sharedAppDelegate` and getting the `descDict` etc.

Comment: Thanks again, I am posting my final code above for everyone to see.