# Obj-C: [NSString stringWithString:@"string"] vs. @"string"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring, stringwithstring

I've seen people do something like `[NSString stringWithString:@"some string"]`. Why not just do `@"some string"`?

For an example, look at the [`facebook-ios-sdk`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBRequest.m#L147).

[+[NSString stringWithString:] -- what's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616348/nsstring-stringwithstring-whats-the-point) is a similar question, but none of the answers address `[NSString stringWithString:@"some string"]` vs. `@"some string"`.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithString:@"some string"]` copies `@"some string"` from read-only memory, which is baked in the executable, but as NSString is immutable anyways, I don't see the point either.

Comment: @WTP, no - it does nothing. See @Sven's answer

Comment: Now we have to use @"some string", otherwise we get this warning "Using 'stringWithString': with a literal is redundant"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually there is no difference. `[NSString stringWithString: str]` just does nothing and returns `str` if `str` is immutable already.

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference other than the extra key strokes needed.  In fact, with a constant string as a parameter (or an immutable string) you just get another pointer to the parameter.

The main use of the method is in subclasses:

```
[NSMutableString stringWithString: @"fdghdfjl"];
```

will give you a mutable autoreleased copy of the original.

Comment: It's also used as an alternative to `[[someString copy] autorelease]` — that is, it guarantees that you have an non-owned immutable string — that some people find more readable, I think.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note about `stringWithString:` is that it will throw an exception if the source string is nil.