# Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, reachability

i used this code in reachability class that is in ios6

```
   switch (status) {
        case kNotReachable:
            statusString = [NSString stringWithString: @"Not Reachable"];
            break;
        case kReachableViaWWAN:
            statusString = [NSString stringWithString: @"Reachable via WWAN"];
            break;
        case kReachableViaWiFi:
            statusString = [NSString stringWithString: @"Reachable via WiFi"];
            break;
    }
```

but the following error is occurred 
"Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant"

Comment: Why not just use the literals by themselves? Rather than using stringWithString

Comment: why don't you use `statusString = @"Not Reachable";` ?

Answer (score 9):

The warning is saying that you could instead easily do like this:

`statusString = @"Not Reachable";`

The explanation is provided in the post 
[Obj-C: [NSString stringWithString:@"string"] vs. @"string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280849/obj-c-nsstring-stringwithstringstring-vs-string)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
statusString = [NSString stringWithString: @"Not Reachable"];
```

please write your code like below:

```
statusString = @"Content-Type: Not Reachable/unknown\r\n\r\n";
```

warning will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You resolve these 'warnings' simply by declaring your strings like so:

```
statusString = @"";
```

instead of

```
statusString = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a type of compiler optimization. Actually you need to assign a string to variable. You can do it directly as `myString = @""` no need to call a method and it will use additional processing time.