# NSJSONSerialization can't handle null values

Tags: ios, ios5

I have some code that looks like this:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];

NSArray *arrRequests = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                         error:nil];

// Loop through the array and generate the necessary annotation views
for (int i = 0; i<= arrRequests.count - 1; i++)
{
    //now let's dig out each and every json object
    NSDictionary *dict = [arrRequests objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *is_private = [NSString
                            stringWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"is_private"]];
                            ...
```

It works when the value for is_private is 1 or 0, but if it is null it crashes with an exception on this line:

```
NSString *is_private = [NSString stringWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"is_private"]];
```

Is there a way to check if it is not null or handle this so that it is able to put nil into the NSString *is_private variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `NSJSONSerialization` and everything to do with the fact that you're passing a `nil` value to `stringWithString:`. Why not just simply that line to `NSString *is_private = [dict objectForKey:@"is_private"];`?

Also, why are you using an `NSString` to store a boolean value? An `NSNumber` would be much better-suited.

Comment: got it! I saw the stringWithString in an example, and didn't pay much attention to it. What is it meant to be there for?  Thanks! I'll accept your answer when StackOverflow allows me to do that.

Comment: To be quite honest, I've never used it. You certainly aren't the first to ask this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616348/nsstring-stringwithstring-whats-the-point

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to handle it like so:

```
id value = [dict valueForKey:@"is_private"];
NSString *is_private = [value isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? nil : value;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check if `[dict objectForKey:@"is_private"]` is `nil` or `[NSNull null]` before passing it to `stringWithString:`?