# Using [NSString stringWithString: someString] vs. [someString copy] when setting instance variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, instance-variables

I'm aware that, when setting instance variables (such as `NSString` variables) in ObjC classes, it's often best practice to ensure the class owns its own variables, e.g.:

```
NSString *someInstanceVariable = [NSString stringWithString: someNSStringObject];
```

My question is, is this different (practically speaking) from the following?

```
NSString *someInstanceVariable = [someNSStringObject copy];
```

Comment: The end result is identical. Both protect you if `someNSStringObject` is really a mutable string.

Comment: Related: [+\[NSString stringWithString:\] -- what's the point?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1616348)

Comment: If you are working with a non-ARC codebase, `stringWithString:` returns an autoreleased value, while `copy` does not. Beyond that there really isn't any difference.

Comment: rmaddy and BergQuester - as I suspected, but wanted to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`+[NSString stringWithString:]` never returns `nil`.

`[someString copy]` returns `nil` if `someString` is `nil`.

Comment: However, `stringWithString:` will throw an exception (app crash), if the parameter is `nil`.