# Memory Leak - Objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057721/objective-c-memory-management)

My code is showing a memory leak here:

```
NSMutableArray* newImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* newMediaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (self.categoryIndex == 0) {
    for (int i=1; i < [categoryArray count]; i++)
    {
        newImageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[newImageArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[self getImageArrayByCategoryIndex:i]]];
    }
}
else {
    newImageArray = [self getImageArrayByCategoryIndex:self.categoryIndex];
}

for (int i=0; i < [newImageArray count]; i++)
{
    Media* media = [[Media alloc] init];
    NSString* imageFile = [newImageArray objectAtIndex: i];

    media.imageFile = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFile];
    media.imageLabel = [[imageFile lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    media.soundFile = [appFolderPath stringByAppendingString:[[[imageFile stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingString: @".wav"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: IMAGES_FOLDER withString: SOUNDS_FOLDER]];

    [newMediaArray addObject:media];
}

self.mediaArray = newMediaArray;

[self setNextMediaIndex];
```

I am not releasing media because it is being used by newMediaArray (which is used by mediaArray, which is used my my main object).  Shouldn't everything get released when I release my main object?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why not choose a user name and make yourself comfortable? Also, just post this code as an edit to your other question.

Comment: In the `if` branch, you are not adding objects to the original `newImageArray`, you are replacing it entirely with another array in each iteration of the `for` loop, leaking the original array (the others are autoreleased). You probably want `[newImageArray addObjectsFromArray:...];`. The `else` branch also leaks the original array since you assign a different array. In the second `for`, you leak the `Media` object in every iteration. After `self.mediaArray = newMediaArray;` you don't release `newMediaArray` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are leaking all over the place in a variety of ways

`newImageArray` gets allocated but never released, additionaly you are overwriting the version that you allocated in the first line of you code with another version. So even if you released it at the end of this code segment, the wrong version would get released. It looks like you don't even need to allocate this one.

`newMediaArray` gets allocated but never released, you assign it to a property `mediaArray` if you are using `@synthesize` to create the code for that property, depending on how you declared that property, the setter will `retain` the value i.e. `newMediaArray` creating a leak.

`media` gets allocated but never released, it get added to a `NSMutableArray` which means it will get retained by the array. If your app crashes when you release `media` in the for loop the problem is somewhere else

The [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) is pretty much a must read

Answer (score 0):

When an NSMutableArray such as `newMediaArray` adds an object, it will retain that object. You don't need to (nor should you) retain the object on the array's behalf. This is fundamentally how memory management in Objective-C works: each object retains the things it references, and releases them when finished. `newMediaArray` is its own object, so it'll manage its own references.

You should release `media` near the end of the body of your `for` loop because you're done using that object. If you don't release it then, you'll lose your reference to it and you'll have no way to release it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
[newMediaArray addObject:media];
```

that means that `newMediaArray` has done a `retain` on `media`. You can then release `media` (you *should*). The `retain` done in the array method will keep it alive as long as the array references it. If you don't release it in your method, the retain count will remain 2, and even if the array releases it, it will still be 1 and not be dealloc-ed.

You could do:

```
Media *media = [[[Media alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then the autorelease pool will release it in time, but not before this method ends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `[media release]` statement at the bottom of the loop. `newMediaArray` should also be released after it is assigned to the `mediArray` property.