# Is this a proper MonoState Design?

Tags: c#, oop, monostate

I have a `Person` Class and based on some help I received in this post.

[MonoState, Singleton, or Derived Forms: Best approach for CRUD app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825617/passing-objects-and-the-singleton-pattern/825820)

I have a `CurrentPerson` class around(??) it and I access the data thru that.

I think I understand how this is supposed to work but it seems that I don't have it *quite* right.

Questions:

1. For starters, shouldn't `Person` and all it's member variables be **private**?
2. Why is `Person`, when declared in `CurrentPerson`, static?  Is that right?
3. `Person` actually has child objects `Address`, `Enrollment`, and `CaseNote`. How do I incorporate them? A `CurrentEnrollment` wrapper around `Enrollment`?

I am fairly new to OOP as an *applied* science so some of these concepts are hard for me to visualize.

The code is long, I apologize.

---

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string SuffixID { get; set; }
    public string TitleID { get; set; }
    public string SocialSn { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string DlNumber { get; set; }
    public string DlStateID { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryRace { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryRace { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string InsertProgram { get; set; }
    public string InsertUserID { get; set; }
    public string UpdateProgram { get; set; }
    public string UpdateUserID { get; set; }
    public string LockID { get; set; }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int ResidencyCountyID { get; set; }
    public int ResponsibilityCountyID { get; set; }

    public bool HispanicOriginFlag { get; set; }
    public bool CitizenFlag { get; set; }
    public bool VeteranFlag { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeathDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }



}

class CurrentPerson
{
    public static Person Person { get; set; }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.FirstName; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.FirstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.LastName; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.LastName = value; }
    }

    public string MiddleName
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.MiddleName; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.MiddleName = value; }
    }

    public string SuffixID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.SuffixID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.SuffixID = value; }
    }

    public string TitleID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.TitleID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.TitleID = value; }
    }

    public string SocialSn
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.SocialSn; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.SocialSn = value; }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.Gender; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.Gender = value; }
    }

    public string DlNumber
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.DlNumber; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.DlNumber = value; }
    }

    public string DlStateID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.DlStateID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.DlStateID = value; }
    }

    public string PrimaryRace
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.PrimaryRace; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.PrimaryRace = value; }
    }

    public string SecondaryRace
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.SecondaryRace; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.SecondaryRace = value; }
    }

    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.EmailAddress; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.EmailAddress = value; }
    }

    public string MaritalStatus
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.MaritalStatus; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.MaritalStatus = value; }
    }

    public string InsertProgram
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.InsertProgram; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.InsertProgram = value; }
    }

    public string InsertUserID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.InsertUserID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.InsertUserID = value; }
    }

    public string UpdateProgram
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateProgram; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateProgram = value; }
    }

    public string UpdateUserID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateUserID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateUserID = value; }
    }

    public string LockID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.LockID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.LockID = value; }
    }

    public int PersonID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.PersonID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.PersonID = value; }
    }

    public int ClientID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.ClientID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.ClientID = value; }
    }

    public int ResidencyCountyID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.ClientID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.ClientID = value; }
    }

    public int ResponsibilityCountyID
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.ResponsibilityCountyID; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.ResponsibilityCountyID = value; }
    }

    public bool HispanicOriginFlag
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.HispanicOriginFlag; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.HispanicOriginFlag = value; }
    }

    public bool CitizenFlag
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.CitizenFlag; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.CitizenFlag = value; }
    }

    public bool VeteranFlag
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.VeteranFlag; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.VeteranFlag = value; }
    }

    public DateTime BirthDate
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.BirthDate; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.BirthDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DeathDate
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.DeathDate; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.DeathDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime InsertDateTime
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.InsertDateTime; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.InsertDateTime = value; }
    }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTime
    {
        get { return CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateDateTime; }
        set { CurrentPerson.Person.UpdateDateTime = value; }
    }


}
```

---

P.S. If Daniel Brückner happens to read this please take no offense as I am not second guessing your answer; I just need deeper clarification on some items in order to properly understand the use of monostate in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding whether the fields should be private, that's just the new (C# 3.0?) way of declaring properties without having a backing variable.  A common variation is

```
public string SomeProperty { get; protected set }
```

'Course, as soon as you want to do something like validation in the setter this doesn't work and you have to go back to writing setters and getters, and declaring a backing variable.

I'm not sure what the intent of the static `CurrentPerson.Person()` method is, or how it gets set.

For the third question, if I understand you right you'd give the `Person` class a property of type `Address` and access it something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(somePerson.HomeAddress.City);
```