# Singleton properties memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton

What attribute better appropriates to singleton's properties?
As I know singleton never deallocated, but I still have to retain its' properties or assign it's more correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to retain and release all of your singleton's properties exactly the [same way](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) that you would for a non-singleton.

This will make things much easier to maintain, especially if one day you (or someone else) have to convert this singleton class into a non-singleton class.

Comment: Also, please be sure that a singleton is really the best solution to your problem. Singletons are really just global variables, and they offer a similar collection of benefits and drawbacks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474613/how-should-i-refactor-my-code-to-remove-unnecessary-singletons