# appDelegate method with Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, appdelegate

I came across SO posts with `incorrect decrement of RC to +0` but none of them where **appDelegate Method** (as per my knowledge *delegate can't be retained* )

Following is the code where im having memory leak

```
    iPlayerAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iPlayerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    int currentTabIndex = appDelegate.tabcontroller.tabBarController.selectedIndex ;

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;


    pageItem* selectedItem = nil;
    selectedItem = [appDelegate.pageData.pageItems objectAtIndex:btn.tag];

    appDelegate.bStatusValue = FALSE;

    if(pageInfo.removeCaptureFile)
    {
        [appDelegate.commonUtils removeFileFromPath:@"snap.jpeg"];
        [appDelegate.commonUtils removeFileFromPath:@"prevSnap.jpeg"];
    }

    if (appDelegate.launchTimer &&[appDelegate.launchTimer isValid]) 
    {
        [appDelegate.launchTimer invalidate];
        appDelegate.launchTimer = nil;          
       // appDelegate.timerFlag = NO;

    }

    NSArray *viewarray = [self.view subviews];

    for(int index=0;index< viewarray.count;index++)
    {

        UIView *view = [viewarray objectAtIndex:index];
        if([view  isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]] || [view  isMemberOfClass:[UITextView class]])   
        {
            [view resignFirstResponder];
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }

        if([view  isMemberOfClass:[scrollwinView class]])  
        {
            scrollwinView* scrollView = (scrollwinView*) view;
            [scrollView stopTimer];
        }

    }

    if(appDelegate.tabsupport)
    { //to remove the cached view from stack after pressing back
        CSNavigationController *navcon= (CSNavigationController*)appDelegate.tabcontroller.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        [navcon removeViewData:pageInfo.screenId];
    }

    int currentscrid=pageInfo.screenId; 
    clrScreenId = pageInfo.clrScreenId;

    if (appDelegate.connMgr) 
    {               
        [appDelegate.connMgr closeHttpStream];
        //[connMgr release];        
        appDelegate.connMgr = nil;
        appDelegate.connectionstatus = FALSE;


        if(appDelegate.initAnimation.startId == 5)      
        {
            appDelegate.transition = NO ;
            [appDelegate readPageData:currentscrid isBack:NO ];
            appDelegate.transition = YES;
            return ;
        }

        [appDelegate stopAnimation];
```

and here is the snapshots of memory leak  Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count [image: Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count] and Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller[image: Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller]

why am i getting this leak? am i reassigning appDelegate object?

I have not called release on the return value of that accessor(appDelegate) nor have set it nil, how should i fix this leak?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

I think you should read this thread about correct usage of the app delegate:

[iPhone proper usage of Application Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338734/iphone-proper-usage-of-application-delegate)

For example, in your code:

```
selectedItem = [appDelegate.pageData.pageItems objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
```

seems very messy. A possible better solution might be to use a singleton design pattern.

As for your memory leak, possibly check that your not retaining anything when your app delegate animations perform animation stop callbacks.

Comment: i know delegate should not be retained and i have not retained the delegate.. if you can figure out the why i am getting the leak please post the solution