# Objective-C best practices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)

Does anybody know a good reference about Objective-C/Cocoa Best Practices? 
Project organization, methodologies, naming and etc.

Comment: In this thread I found this document
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml. That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See question

[What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

A great "K&R" style reference for objective-c is [Programming in Objective C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325861) by Stephen G. Kochan.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Matt. I'm looking for something specific, not about the language itself, but how to organize projects, how to deal with project versions and stuffs like that. Do you think this book can help me?

Answer (score 1):

As for versioning, definitely set up a version control system. I wrote a tutorial on that [here](http://appletutorials.net/2009/07/setting-up-subversion-with-versions-and-beanstalk/).