# UIView alpha value compare error

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

At first, I set a view's alpha to 0.4, I want to some actions later when aView.alpha == 0.4, but the compare failed.

Code:

```
aView.alpha = 0.4;
...//never changes aView.alpha.
if (aView.alpha == 0.4) {
    //this compare failed.
}
```

BUT, when I set the alpha to 0.5, it works!

```
aView.alpha = 0.5;
...
if (aView.alpha == 0.5) {
    //it's OK.
}
```

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never compare floats using equality. It can work (apparently "positive zero" and "negative zero" are exact values) but you need to check that there is a very small difference, not that they are equal. Like:

```
#define TINY_DELTA (.0001f)

if(fabsf(floatA - floatB) < TINY_DELTA) {
    // equal for all intensive porpoises
}
```

(Actually you have doubles there. [In general, use "0.5f" to use floats.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1622729/189804) It is generally faster on most of the hardware out there.)